# Insert elements at <script> tag position

Tags: javascript, embed

When sites give you some JavaScript that you paste into a web page to have content inserted at that position, how does the script determine its current position in the DOM? Without using document.write?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Do you have an example of where that is being done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At script inclusion time, it's certain that the last `<script>` in the page will be the current one; the rest of the page hasn't been parsed yet. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts= document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var this_script= scripts[scripts.length-1];

    // Something that happens later...
    //
    setTimeout(function() {
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello!'));
        this_script.parentNode.insertBefore(div, this_script);
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

This holds true as long as the script tag doesn't use `defer`, or HTML5's `async`.

Comment: Didn't realize that it would work that way, but makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking out for the answer myself, my situation was "Create a dynamic src and add it to script element at one fixed place".

```
<script>Other code</script>
//Add my dynamically calculated script right here
```

I had used something like this

```
<script>document.write('<script src="myJs.js?v=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

It worked, but lighthouse audit marked it a bad practice. To improve my performance score, I had to remove the document.write, which was used at multiple places.
I wrote below function and called it wherever I wanted to add such scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertScriptHere(src){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute("src", src + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
        document.currentScript.insertAdjacentElement('afterEnd', script);
    }
</script>
....
<script>insertScriptHere("myJs.js?v=");</script>
```

Now this is working and the flag "avoid use of document.write()" is no longer there in audit report.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why such scripts would care about their location in the DOM, but I guess it's possible to determine. Maybe use something like [document.scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537487(VS.85).aspx) to start your search.

Comment: I don't see the document.scripts in the Mozilla reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document

So I'm guessing that's an IE-only thing? Could be wrong though, I'm running Chrome and don't feel like checking! :) Thanks though.

Comment: It's an IE extension from way back, that's also available on WebKit and Opera. Although since it doesn't give you anything that `getElementsByTagName` doesn't already do, it's never really seen much use.