# Getting the id of a button just clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a calculator webapp using JS and I'm running into some problems. I looked at other open threads and tried that code but it didn't seem to work. I'm currently just trying to log the ID of the button that was pressed, but when I press a button all I get is `"undefined"` back. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="text">
<table border="0" id="table">
  <tr>
  <td><input type="button" id="one" value="1" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="two" value="2" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="three" value="3" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><input type="button" id="four" value="4" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="five" value="5" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="six" value="6" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><input type="button" id="seven" value="7" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="eight" value="8" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="nine" value= "9" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td><input type="button" id="zero" value="0" onClick="calculate();"></td>
  </tr>

</table>




<script>
function calculate(){
console.log(this.id);
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-get-the-id-of-the-button-clicked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function calculate(){
   var e = window.event,
       btn = e.target || e.srcElement;
   alert(btn.id);
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/ihajon/edit#preview)

*Explanation:*

[window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) holds an information about last occured event. In your case , it's `'click'` event. You can retrieve the `DOM Element`,which is being clicked, from the `event` object.The `target` or `srcElement` property (depends on type of the browser) represents that `DOM Element`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked out great. Any chance you can give a little explanation at whats going on for these two lines?

   var e = window.event,
       btn = e.target || e.srcElement;

Comment: @KyleSmith See the explanation section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target` to get the element.

```
<input type="button" id="one" value="1" onclick="calculate(event);">
<script>
function calculate(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc(e) {
        console.log(e.id);
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="calc(this)" />
```

You need put a lot more effort into self study :-) Knowledge is never gained unless an effort is made.

Answer (score 0):

If your hard writing them in as it appears you are above, you could just pass the id value as a parameter to the function

```
onClick="calculate(one)";
onClick="calculate(two)";
onClick="calculate(three)";
```

etc...

It's not terrible efficient but should work for your case. Then your function can be something like:

```
function calculate(number){
alert(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
onclick=alert(this.id)
```

or,in your case :

```
onclick=calculate()
```

Script:

```
function calculate(){
  alert(this.id)
  //this.id - hold the value of the id of the button just click
}
```