# I trying to get the target element's id when function fired, but `this` keyword returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I trying to capture the target element's id when function fired, but `this`  keyword returns `undefined`

--- HTML file. --- (I can't add any parameter in `onclick` function)
I have many `<a>` tag in the page and want to identify witch `<a>` tag was clicked.

```
<a href="#some_links" id="element_id" onclick = "object.pageName.functionName('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">Get this object</a>

<a href="#some_links" id="second_element_id" onclick = "object.pageName.functionName('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">Get this object</a>
```

--- .js file ---

```
object.pageName.functionName = function(a, b, c){
    alert(this); // returns 'undefined'
}
```

Comment: Just path this in params http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-get-the-id-of-the-button-clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common question here on StackOverflow.

In short, your onclick gets wrapped in an anonymous function (which does have access to `this`. You have to pass it along.

--- HTML file. ---

```
<a href="#some_links" id="element_id" onclick = "object.pageName.functionName(this, 'parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">Get this object</a>
```

--- .js file ---

```
object.pageName.functionName = function(self, a, b, c){
    alert(self); // returns 'undefined'
}
```

Here is another way:

```
object.pageName.functionName = function(a, b, c){
    // Downside of this way, you can only use this function for one element.
    self = document.getElementById("element_id");
    alert(self);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to add 'this' parameter in the onclick function.

Comment: Question -- I'm curious as to what kind of work environment asks you to do a job but doesn't give you the power to do it.  Answer updated, BTW.

Comment: this works for only one anchor, but what if there are many tag in the page and need identify witch <a> tag was clicked.

Comment: There is only one correct solution: Pass `this` as a parameter.  If you can't do that, then you'll have to find another solution based off what I gave you.  I've shown you the problem.  I've told you the solution **and** I've given you a work-around.