# How to identify that which element was clicked without modified the onclick function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I trying to get the target element's id when function fired, but `this` keyword returns `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490110/i-trying-to-get-the-target-elements-id-when-function-fired-but-this-keyword-r)

--- HTML file ---

```
<a href="#link_1" id="id_0" onclick = "getElement('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">0</a>
<a href="#link_2" id="id_1" onclick = "getElement('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">1</a>
<a href="#link_1" id="id_2" onclick = "getElement('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3')">2</a>
```

--- Js file ---

```
function getElement = function(a, b, c){
    // trying to get the clicked element
    alert(this); // returns 'undefined'
}
```

**Note**: I can't modify / add / remove parameters in `onclick` function, but I can add / remove parameters in js file

**Problem**: How to identify that which element was clicked without modifying the `onclick` function parameters?

Comment: I think [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) might help

Comment: event.target wont help because the snippet does not include jQuery

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher That also seems to require you to send "this" as a parameter.

Comment: @williamcarswell Then I'll add this: include jQuery :p

Comment: @Keyser -- Yes.  It is the same code, same poster and same issue.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Oh I missed that :) Well it's definitely a duplicate then, but the accepted answer seems to be missing the correct solution for this guy though (or rather, there isn't one). So why did he accept it and post a duplicate? Why K.K, why!?

Comment: @Keyser -- Mine was the accepted answer.  I'm assuming he accepted cause I did post a work-around, but the work around isn't pretty -- requires too much code duplication.  He's looking for a simpler answer.

Comment: @williamcarswell: the event object is not part of jQuery, you don't need it to get to the event

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Yes I noticed :p But as you mentioned yourself, that won't work with more than one link.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: i asked again because your answer works but not as i need, i am not able to add this keyword in the onclick function, thats why i asked again.

Comment: @K.K -- It would have been better to to have edited your question with a new title rather than start a new one.  That way, the whole discussion would stay together.  Now, someone will have to read two separate posts.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I know but what Keyser was refering to was a jQuery documentation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

Change the HTML to:

```
<a href="#link_1" id="id_0" onclick = "getElement('parms1', 'parms2', 'parms3',this,event)">0</a>
```

And the function definition to:

```
//function getElement = function(){};doesn't really make sense...
function getElement (a, b, c,clicked,e)
{
    alert(clicked.id);//alerts id of clicked link
    alert((e.target || e.srcElement).id);//via the event object
}
```

So the choice is yours, either pass `this` and `event` to the function, or just `event`, or just `this` and you're good to go.

You might want to look into delegating this type of events, though