# How to identify an element using an onclick event handler

Tags: javascript

I want to send the ID of an element to the function to know what button pressed it.

```
<input type="submit" id="foo" onclick="function(abcxyz)" value="abc" />
<input type="submit" id="foo" onclick="function(xyz)" value="x" />

function(str){
    if(str == abcxyz){
        //do this.
    }
    else if(str == xyz){
        //do that.
    }
}
```

or if it's possible, its okay that the value abc or x will be send to the function.
so **str = abc** or **str = x.**

Comment: The rule is, ID of an element should be unique in that page.

Comment: sorry for that, I just copy and paste the input and added new value.
my mistake.
And yes your right, it must be unique because its an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly...

1. You are missing a function name
2. The two inputs have the same id
3. using submit for type doesn't make sense in your case
4. The values of the inputs aren't needed for this task

   ```
   <input type="button" id="foo1" onclick="button_click('1')" />
   <input type="button" id="foo2" onclick="button_click('2')" />`

   function button_click(str){
       if(str == '1'){
           alert('Button with id foo1 was pressed');
       }
       else if(str == '2'){
           alert('Button with id foo2 was pressed');
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is what i needed.
the rest of the answers are useful.
Thanks guys, SOF the best..

Comment: @user2045458 If you find an answer useful, you should vote it up.

Comment: @alu1024 Maybe it's better to use a `switch` statement in the `button_click` function to be more future proof. Also, you can do `button_click(this.id)` to create more reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [answer that you'll find here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button).

Basically write

```
<input type="submit" onclick="yourFunction(this.id)" id="abc" value="Button abc" />
```

Comment: ID's cannot be only numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a name:

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whichButton(str){
        if(str == 'abc'){
            alert('abc was clicked');
        }
        else if(str == 'x'){
            alert('str was clicked');
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" id="foo" onclick="whichButton(this.value);" value="abc" />
<input type="submit" id="foo1" onclick="whichButton(this.value);" value="x" />
```

Comment: Oh come on, give them different IDs!

Comment: Nice Sean.. how about abcxyz value.
like when i will use
<a href="#" id="foo" onclick="whichButton(abcxyz);">abc</a>
can i compare str == abxyz

if its not possible to href then input will be okay.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add another `else if` in the function.

Comment: @Sean I think a `switch` statement would be more appropriate and future proof in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please refer the code snippet mentioned below

E.g

```
  <input type="submit" id="foo" onclick="function(this.value)" value="abc" />
  <input type="submit" id="foo" onclick="function(this.value)" value="x" />
```

In above code snippet this object will refer to event source i.e submit button