# How to fetch the id of dynamically generating divs and display a message by using that id?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to fetch the id of the dynamically generating div from the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ramapriya/FJhDw/2/ and display distinct message, if we click on each div

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

var columns = 10, container = $("#container"), width = (100 / columns);

$("head").append("<style>.col { width: " + width + "%;} .row {  height: " + width + "%  }</style>");

for(var ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++) {
    container.append("<div class=\"row\" />");
    row = $("#container > div:last-child");

    for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

        row.append("<div class=\"col\" style=\"background: " + get_random_color() + "\">szin</div>");

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any dynamically created `id` attribute in your example.

Comment: You mean on click on DIVs .col, your DIVs don't have any id, otherwise, as you are using jq 1.6.4 in jsfiddle, you should delegate event using .delegate() method or worst, set click handler for each .col

Comment: Check this, it might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button

Comment: I think you have to set ids of Div elements at the time of their generation and also have to bind a function to show message on their click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use the onclick attribute; that does not belong in your HTML, because it has nothing to do with layout or appearance. Keep your functionality in the JS where it belongs. Simply implement an ID scheme using your iterators, as below, and define a click handler.

See this example at http://jsfiddle.net/XXd6z/. Also, note that I've cleaned up your element generation, which was difficult to read before. jQuery makes it easy to create nice-looking elements on the fly.

```
var columns = 10,
    container = $("#container"),
    width = (100 / columns);

$("head").append("<style>.col { width: " + width + "%;} .row {  height: " + width + "%  }</style>");

for (var ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++) {
    var $row = $("<div />", {
        class: "row"
    });
    container.append($row);

    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        var $col = $("<div />", {
            class: "col",
            style: "background: " + get_random_color() + ";",
            html: "sample",
            id : ii + "-" + i
        });
        $row.append($col);
    }
}

$("div.col").click(function () {
    alert(this.id + " " + $(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this it will generate dynamic ids and when you click any div it will show the alert with that div id :-

```
row.append("<div id=\"div_" + ii + "_" + i + "\" onclick=\"alert(this.id)\" class=\"col\" style=\"background: " + get_random_color() + "\">sample</div>");
```

Here is the fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/FJhDw/5/

Answer (score 0):

To specify `div` you should provide an `id` to each `div` and you can execute a javascript function to each `div` at creation time.

Ex: On click if you need id of div then you can add `onclick` attribute to `div` and pass it to function

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FJhDw/3/)

updated: [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FJhDw/6/)

Comment: id should be unique but in your demo i am getting repeated id of first row to all the remaining rows.

Comment: Id is "myDiv" apppending div number. I checked it. e.g: myDiv0, myDiv1 etc. @user2089987

Comment: Your "ID" is the same for all the divs in the same column, meaning it's not an "ID"