# Is there a way to capture the id of the dom element in a variable?

Tags: html, dom, this

I have an element in "this" how do i get its id's value  (and class's value)?

```
alert(this.id) ;
```

returns undefined.

Comment: What is the output for `alert(this)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probable [duplicate for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button/4825325#4825325).

You need to send the ID as the function parameters. Do it like this:

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script>
```

This will send the ID `this.id` as `clicked_id` which you can use in your function. [**See it in action here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/R77EB/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should check if `this` is really your target element and not global `window` object. Let me illustrate my advice:

```
function foo() {
  if (this === window) {
    alert("'this' is actually 'window'");
  } else {
    alert("'this' is not 'window'");
  }
}

foo(); // will alert: 'this' is actually 'window'
```

but:

```
document.onclick = foo;
// every mouse click will produce alert: 'this' is not 'window'
```

Anyway, I'd suggest you to use Firebug/Chrome console to inspect the real value of `this` object:

```
console.log(this); // will reveal you the real nature of _this_ ;-)
```