# Javascript get div id from onclicked function

Tags: javascript

I have some buttons with the same `onClick` function. Inside this `onClick` function I want to check which ID is pressed. Each button has a different ID.

How would I go about returning the ID of the button that is clicked?

Comment: Why do you want to know the id?

Comment: @AndersLindén why not :)

Comment: What would you use the id for?

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, it's just the `element.id`. Here's an example **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9erkH/)**

```
function clicked(e) {
    alert( this.id );   
}
```

The above is the callback function for your click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFn(){

    // your code;
    alert( this.id );

}
```

will do the job if you're calling your function like i.e:

```
var $btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for(var i=0; i<$btn.length; i++) $btn[i].addEventListener('click', myFn, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button click, pass the id of that button

```
<button id="btn1" onClick="btnclick(this.id)">button1</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function btnclick(btnid)
{
    alert(btnid);
}
</script>
```

Else if you are not passing ID as parameter to the click handler

```
<button id="btn1" onClick="btnclick()">button1</button>

function btnclick(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (e.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        alert(e.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 'this' to your method to identify the caller.

```
<button id="1" type="button"onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me!</h1>
```

and refer to it with id as suggested by LaughDonor

```
function myFunction(entity)
{  
    alert(entity.id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i would use $(this).attr('id') (if you are using jquery)  Can you post your code?

If you're not using Jquery, I'd pass the id as a parameter in the onclick function. Without actually seeing your code, it will be harder to tell.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button) for more context.