# pop-up on click of a button in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I have the following code in my JSP

```
function doContractAction(actionUrl) {

        var strActionUrl = actionUrl;
        if(strActionUrl !=null) {
            document.forms[0].action = actionUrl;
            document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        return false;
    }

<div id="content">
    <div id="report">
    <s:form name="openControl" id="myActionForm" theme="simple" action="ShowAlertReports" method="post">
        <div id="accordion">

            <s:iterator id="alertCat" value="alerts" status="status" >

                <h2  style="font-size:1.1em; padding-top:0px;padding-left:1px;padding-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">
                <p align="left"><s:property value="%{key}"/></p>
                </h2>
                <br>
                <div>

                    <table id="${status.index}" class="grid one-em-below constant-left-width" cellspacing="0" d="ad-hoc-reports">
                        <thead class="nosort">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="sortAsc" onclick="applySort(this);"><a style="cursor:pointer; color: #0066FF; font-weight:bold;">Alert Name </a></th>
                                <th scope="col" onclick="applySort(this);"><a style="cursor:pointer; color: #0066FF; font-weight:bold;">Customer Name</a></th>
                                <th scope="col" onclick="applySort(this);"><a style="cursor:pointer; color: #0066FF; font-weight:bold;">Date Opened</a></th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead >
                        <tbody style="font-size:12px;">
                            <s:iterator id="alertsubcat" value="%{value}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <s:property value="name"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <s:property value="customerName"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="font-size:11px;">
                                        <s:if test="%{display=='OK'}">
                                        <input type="button" value='<s:property value="%{display}" />'
                                            onclick='return closeInfoAlert("<s:property value="%{alertsNotificationId}" />");' />
                                        </s:if>

                                        <s:else>
                                            <input type="button" value='<s:property value="%{display}" />' 
                                            onclick='return doContractAction("<s:property value="%{url}" />");' />
                                        </s:else>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </s:iterator>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
        </div>
    <s:hidden name="description" id="description" value=""/>
    </s:form>
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Now `<p align="left"><s:property value="%{key}"/></p>` can have values

1. Alert1, Alert2 Alert3 and so on

My requirement is from code

```
<s:else>
    <input type="button" value='<s:property value="%{display}" />' 
    onclick='return doContractAction("<s:property value="%{url}" />");' />
</s:else>
```

I need to pass the **value="%{key}** which will be checked in the  function **doContractAction** 
and I can check the value in key and if it equals **Alert1  or Alert 2** .
I open a pop-up window

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: url is defined in a Java class in a function getURL i.e
public String getURL() { // some code return url; }

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to achieve :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a struts2 counter to give unique id's to each element in loop,I have given a link to refer counter in struts2
[here](https://javabirds.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/struts2-counter/)

Now give unique id's to `Button` and to `<p>`, Now you will have elements given as below

```
<p id="p-0" align="left"> <input id="input-0" type="button"> 
<p id="p-1" align="left"> <input id="input-1" type="button"> 
...
<p id="p-n" align="left"> <input id="input-n" type="button">
```

Now you can pass id of the button using `this.id` you can refer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Now you  can split `input-id`  and counstruct `p-id` . Once you get `p-id`. Now you can get value of the `p` by using 
[getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)