# Button on click creates alert to show data-id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button like so:

```
<button data-id="1" onclick="showID()">Show ID</button>
```

And a function:

```
<script>
  function showID() {
   alert(($(this).data("id")));
  }
 </script>
```

I just want the data-id to be shown in the alert box. I've also tried

```
alert(($(this).data("id")));
```

But again nothing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
function showID(button) {
  alert($(button).attr('data-id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="1" onclick="showID(this)">Show ID</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou. Could i then give data-id a variable and output that instead?

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` inside your click function indicates to either `global` in sloppy mode or `undefined` in strict mode.

You need to do like this:

```
<button data-id="1" onclick="showID(this)">Show ID</button>

<script>
  function showID(elem) {
   alert(($(elem).data("id")));
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Good answer. Enlighten the OP further by providing an example with jQuery  `on("click")`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `this` will not give you the right value, your code should be this way:

```
<button data-id="1" onclick="showID(this)">Show ID</button>
```

Then

```
<script>
  function showID(e) {
  alert(($(e).data("id")));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't work the way you are trying.

pass `this` on click.

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/wfaf7w0t/)**.

Here is the snippet.

```js
function showID(ele) {
  alert(($(ele).attr("data-id")));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="1" onclick="showID(this)">Show ID</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is an example, you have to pass the id to function in the button tag:

[JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825295/5190019)