# How to find the ID of an element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I have is a `class` of `table` `row`s that, when one of them is clicked, activates a `function` in jQuery capturing the `id` of the `element` that was clicked. I have seen several posts on how to do this (i.e [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event) or [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)), but none of them have worked for me.

So, I thought that this would work:

```
$(".yourStockTabs").click(function() {
    if (sellStockClicked === true) {
        var ids = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(ids);
    }
});
```

But it does not. The `sellStockClicked === true` part is the checker to make sure that a `button` has already been previously clicked. I figured at first maybe the code to get the `attribute` was incorrect or maybe the `variable` wasn't true, but I found that neither of these were the case because I removed the `if` `function` and commented out the `id` part and just had it `alert` something, but it still did not.

Here is the full code:

```
$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
    var sellStockClicked = true;
    alert("Please click on the row of the stock that you would like to sell.\n\nWhen you are finished, click this button again.");
    $(".yourStockTabs").css("background", "#E50000");
    $(".yourStockTabs").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
$(".yourStockTabs").click(function() {
    if (sellStockClicked === true) {
        var ids = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(ids);
    }
});
$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
    if (sellStockClicked === true) {
       var sellStockClicked = false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: ^ Basically your click handler should be `$(document).on("click", ".yourStockTabs", function() { ...})`

Comment: Great! This combined with the accepted answer made it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your variable   `sellStockClicked` is declared inside a function.

try removing this variable declaration outside as  :

```
var sellStockClicked ;
$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
    sellStockClicked = true;
    alert("Please click on the row of the stock that you would like to sell.\n\nWhen you are finished, click this button again.");
    $(".yourStockTabs").css("background", "#E50000");
    $(".yourStockTabs").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
$(".yourStockTabs").click(function() {
    if (sellStockClicked === true) {
        var ids = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(ids);
    }
});
$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
    if (sellStockClicked === true) {
       var sellStockClicked = false; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const e = document.body;
e.addEventListener("click" , e => {
console.log(e.target.id);
});
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="clickme" id="itsmiId">
<input type="text" placeholder="clickme" id="wowclickme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you looking for this:

```
var sellStockClicked = true;
var ids = [];

$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
  alert("Please click on the row of the stock that you would like to sell.\n\nWhen you are finished, click this button again.");
  $(".yourStockTabs").css("background", "#E50000");
  $(".yourStockTabs").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
$(".yourStockTabs").click(function() {
  if (sellStockClicked === true) {
    ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
    alert(ids);
  }
});
$("#sellStockButton").click(function() {
  if (sellStockClicked === true) {
    sellStockClicked = false; 
  }
});
```