# Clicking a single button changes multiple related images on a page. How to adapt this for multiple buttons, EACH with multiple related images?

Tags: image, onclick, getelementbyid

The following code works to change multiple related images on the same page when a single button is clicked:

```
<!-- RR buttons -->
<div class="wrapper-9">
<button onclick="changeImage()" id="2" class="box">2</button>
</div>

<!-- RR images -->
<img id="theFirstImage" src="RR/images/singles/RR-1.png">
<img id="theSecondImage" src="RR/images/rhythm-1.png">
<img id="theThirdImage" src="RR/images/riff-1.png">


<script>
function changeImage()
{
document.getElementById('theFirstImage').src="RR/images/singles/RR-2.png";
document.getElementById('theSecondImage').src="RR/images/rhythm-2.png";
document.getElementById('theThirdImage').src="RR/images/riff-2.png";
}
</script>
```

How can I adapt this code to accommodate MANY different buttons, not just one? I have 54 buttons in total. My naming convention ensures that the buttons and the images all correlate by number: that is to say, button "2" corresponds to images "RR-2.png", "rhythm-2.png", and "riff-2.png"; button "46" corresponds to "RR-46.png", "rhythm-46.png", and "riff-46.png". The solution must have to do with excerpting the numeral from the id of the given button, and then inserting it in the source call... but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried this, to no avail:

```
<!-- RR buttons -->
<div class="wrapper-9">
<button onclick="changeImage()" id="1" class="box">1</button>
<button onclick="changeImage()" id="2" class="box">2</button>
<button onclick="changeImage()" id="3" class="box">3</button>
</div>

<!-- RR images -->
<img id="theFirstImage" src="RR/images/singles/RR-1.png">
<img id="theSecondImage" src="RR/images/rhythm-1.png">
<img id="theThirdImage" src="RR/images/riff-1.png">

<script>
function changeImage()
{
var currentLabel = $(this).closest('.box').find('button').attr("id");
document.getElementById('theFirstImage').src="RR/images/singles/RR-'" + currentLabel + "'.png";
document.getElementById('theSecondImage').src="RR/images/rhythm-'" + currentLabel + "'.png";
document.getElementById('theThirdImage').src="RR/images/riff-'" + currentLabel + "'.png";
}
</script>
```

Would welcome any insight into what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, solved it! Found the answer here: [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button#4825325)

```
<!-- RR buttons -->
<div class="wrapper-9">
<button class="box" id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">1</button>
<button class="box" id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">2</button>
<button class="box" id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">3</button>
</div>

<!-- RR images -->
<img id="theFirstImage" src="RR/images/singles/RR-1.png">
<img id="theSecondImage" src="RR/images/rhythm-1.png">
<img id="theThirdImage" src="RR/images/riff-1.png">


<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
document.getElementById('theFirstImage').src="RR/images/singles/RR-" + clicked_id + ".png";
document.getElementById('theSecondImage').src="RR/images/rhythm-" + clicked_id + ".png";
document.getElementById('theThirdImage').src="RR/images/riff-" + clicked_id + ".png";
}
</script>
```