# Getting id on click from the same class

Tags: javascript

So, I have 10 balls with the same class and different ids from one to ten.

```
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class="circle ball" id="1"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
            <figure class="circle ball" id="2"><span class="shadow"></span> 
    </figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
    <figure class=" circle ball" id="3"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
```

...

How can I get on click id that is a number and that is stored in variable?
I tried querySelector but it only gets me first match, then querySelectorAll but it returns nodelist... I am fairly new to js so if someone have some solution...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the id"?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825325/9766215).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Comment: I mean that i want to querySelect class and then addEventListener(click) that will return that element id whenever it is clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code snippet and click on the green boxes ...

```js
var balls = document.querySelectorAll('.ball');   // get all balls

balls.forEach(function(ball){  // loop over all balls to use every ball
    ball.addEventListener('click', function(){  // every ball needs to listen on "click" event
        console.log('The ball id is: ' + this.id); // when clicked log the id.
    });
});
```

```css
.ball {
    background-color:green;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class="circle ball" id="1"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
            <figure class="circle ball" id="2"><span class="shadow"></span> 
    </figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
    <figure class=" circle ball" id="3"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll('.circle.ball')` to get all those elements that belong to that class and then use `addEventListener()` to assign `click` event. After that you can get the `id` value by `this.id` when you click an element.

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.circle.ball');
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
  elem[i].addEventListener('click',clickCircle);
}

function clickCircle(){
  console.log(this.id)
}
```

```html
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class="circle ball" id="1"><span class="shadow">1</span></figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
            <figure class="circle ball" id="2"><span class="shadow">2</span> 
    </figure>
        </section>
        <section class="stage" >
    <figure class=" circle ball" id="3"><span class="shadow">3</span></figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ball').forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class="circle ball" id="1"><span class="shadow"></span></figure> 
</section>
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class="circle ball" id="2"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
<section class="stage" >
    <figure class=" circle ball" id="3"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("circle ball");
var i;
var yourId;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    yourId = x[i].id;
}
```

Comment: You should create a working snippet of that code. Also, it can be slightly enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.querySelector` only returns one element.

To target multiple elements, you have to use `.querySelectorAll`.
Then you can use `.forEach` to add a listener on all your elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ball').forEach(function(ball) {
  ball.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('You clicked id:', this.id);
  });
});
```

```css
.ball {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 20px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="stage">
  <figure class="circle ball" id="1"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
<section class="stage">
  <figure class="circle ball" id="2"><span class="shadow"></span>
  </figure>
</section>
<section class="stage">
  <figure class=" circle ball" id="3"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
</section>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your html:

```
onclick="myFunction(this)"
```

Then this in your js file:

```
myFunction(item){
  console.log(item)
}
```