# Using 'this' in JS function to update innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, this

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game with plain JavaScript.  I have three divs with choices for rock, paper, or scissors, which the user can click.  I have another empty div which I would like to update with the text of the div the user clicks on ('rock', 'paper', or 'scissors').  However, the text shows up as 'undefined' each time.  My code is below. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const yourChoice = document.querySelector('#your-choice');

function userChoice() {
  yourChoice.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="your-choice-container">
  <div id="your-choice"></div>
</div>

<div id="choice-container">
  <div class="choice" id="rock" onclick="userChoice()">Rock</div>
  <div class="choice" id="paper" onclick="userChoice()">Paper</div>
  <div class="choice" id="scissors" onclick="userChoice()">Scissors</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the object you are referencing as a parameter. Calling this on the function calls the scope of the function. not the object

```js
const yourChoice = document.querySelector('#your-choice');

function userChoice(obj) {
  yourChoice.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="your-choice-container">
  <div id="your-choice"></div>
</div>

<div id="choice-container">
  <div class="choice" id="rock" onclick="userChoice(this)">Rock</div>
  <div class="choice" id="paper" onclick="userChoice(this)">Paper</div>
  <div class="choice" id="scissors" onclick="userChoice(this)">Scissors</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When called without context, and outside of [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), `this` inside of a function will be `window`, and `window.innerHTML` is undefined, because there's no such global variable.

In general, you should not use the event attributes (like `onclick`), but instead take a look at [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with "this". One way is to pass in an argument in the function like below.

[Here are some more solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

```js
const yourChoice = document.querySelector('#your-choice');

function userChoice(chosen) {
  yourChoice.innerHTML = chosen;
}
```

```html
<div id="your-choice-container">
  <div id="your-choice"></div>
</div>

<div id="choice-container">
  <div class="choice" id="rock" onclick="userChoice('Rock')">Rock</div>
  <div class="choice" id="paper" onclick="userChoice('Paper')">Paper</div>
  <div class="choice" id="scissors" onclick="userChoice('Scissors')">Scissors</div>
</div>
```