# Using PHP and Javascript to display unique ID of generated button

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I am currently building a stock market simulator and, on my main stock market menu, I have 15 'Buy' buttons for each individual company. I have generated the 15 buttons and stock names using the following code:

**HTML and PHP:**

```
for ($a = 0; $a < $length; $a++)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style = 'text-align:center;font-size:15pt'>" . $companyNames[$a] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style = 'text-align:center;font-size:15pt'>" . $companyTickers[$a] . "</td>";
  ?> <td style = "text-align:center;font-size:15pt" id = "<?php echo $priceIdentifiers[$a]; ?>"></td>
  <td style = "text-align:center;font-size:15pt" id = "<?php echo $lowPriceIdentifiers[$a]; ?>"></td>
  <td style = "text-align:center;font-size:15pt" id = "<?php echo $highPriceIdentifiers[$a]; ?>"></td>
  <td style = 'text-align:center;font-size:15pt'><button id = "<?php echo $a; ?>" onclick = "myFunction()" style = 'font-size:12pt'><strong>BUY</strong></button></td>
  <?php echo "</tr>";
}
  ?>
```

Where the value of $length = 15. I have further created a function in Javascript in an attempt to display the unique ID that was generated for each button (from $a) using the following code:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
var a = <? echo json_encode($a); ?>;
function myFunction(){
  window.alert(a);
}
</script>
```

When I am pressing the buttons using the above code, every time I press a button it increments the value that is displayed to me each time (so for 5 button presses, the display is "5", for 8 it is "8").

When looking at an approach on a different post: [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button), I included some of the code in the post and to test my results, I clicked on several random buttons and was greeted with "15" every time.

My target is for the program to display "1" when I press the top button or "4" when I press the fourth button and so on. What can I go about doing to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Comment: @Difster I investigated that post in my research and tried the above method, however when testing out the code the result, when pressing any of the buttons on my page, was "15". I believe that it must be to do with the fact that when pressing the button that $a is already equal to 15 but I am not aware of how to change it to its respective value depending on what button has been pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP but what if you changed the onclick event to pass the value of $a to your JS function?

```
<td style = 'text-align:center;font-size:15pt'><button id = "<?php echo $a; ?>" onclick = "myFunction('<?php echo $a; ?>')" style = 'font-size:12pt'><strong>BUY</strong></button></td>
```

Then in the JS function take the value as a param

```
function myFunction(a){
  window.alert(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the solution for me. I personally thought that $a was passed to my JS function when I wrote that same expression for my ID earlier but that did not work out for me. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @LeoChashchin You should use miken32's answer. Learn about Event Listener Instead of this old way.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a library like jQuery to do things like this. Using attributes like `onclick` is a very outdated way to do things. Even without a library making things easy, it's still pretty simple to do this properly.

```
<?php for ($a = 0; $a < $length; $a++): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="centered"><?=$companyNames[$a]?></td>
        <td class="centered"><?=$companyTickers[$a]?></td>
        <td class="centered" id="<?=$priceIdentifiers[$a]?>"></td>
        <td class="centered" id="<?=$lowPriceIdentifiers[$a]?>"></td>
        <td class="centered" id="<?=$highPriceIdentifiers[$a]?>"></td>
        <td class="centered">
            <button class="buybutton" data-identifier="<?=$a?>"><strong>BUY</strong></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Note I've used alternative syntax on the `for` loop and short echo tags to keep things neat when integrating PHP and HTML.

Now, in your script you can hook into that class name `buybutton` using something like this (again, much easier with a library helping you.)

```
<script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buybutton");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // this reads the value of the data-identifier attribute
      var identifier = this.dataset.identifier;
      window.alert(identifier);
  }, false);
}
</script>
```

The class names also provide a hook for CSS so you aren't repeating inline style rules over and over and over again.

Here's a live example:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buybutton");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var identifier = this.dataset.identifier;
      window.alert(identifier);
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.buybutton { font-weight: bold; color: blue; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>
    <button class="buybutton" data-identifier="1">BUY</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>
    <button class="buybutton" data-identifier="2">BUY</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td>
    <button class="buybutton" data-identifier="3">BUY</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will start to learn about jQuery and how to integrate it into my code.