# Delete particular button (from DOM) on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9f1hakoy/)

`createBtns` function create as many buttons as `data` array is long.

What I want to do is to delete (from DOM) single button when we click on it. The problem is all buttons has the same class, they are all the same, except text value inside of each. There should be a way to get to know which button has been clicked and delete this and only one, but I don't know it.

There is `btnClick` function which should do it (it alerts for now).

```
var data = [
  {name: "Date", value: "12/31/2018", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Car", value: "Ford", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Country", value: "Russia", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Age", value: "20", type: "visible"},
];

var outer = $(".outerPanel");

var createBtns = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
    var name = data[i].name;
    var value = data[i].value;

    btn.html(name + ": " + value);
    btn.click(() => btnClick());
    outer.append(btn);
  }
}

var btnClick = () => {
    alert("test");
}

createBtns();
```

Comment: Inside the click handler, you can access the button via `this` or the function's first argument: `btn.click(btnClick);` and `var btnClick = e => { // access e.target }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [
  {name: "Date", value: "12/31/2018", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Car", value: "Ford", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Country", value: "Russia", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Age", value: "20", type: "visible"},
];

var outer = $(".outerPanel");

var createBtns = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
    var name = data[i].name;
    var value = data[i].value;

    btn.html(name + ": " + value);
    btn.click((e) => btnClick(e));
    outer.append(btn);
  }
}

var btnClick = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.remove()
}

createBtns();
```

I assume $ is JQuery?

**edit: (from comments)**

*And if I'd like to also update data array, how would it look like? I mean delete the object from data when button disappears*

On this I can think of two kind of approach, the first is to embed the data into the button

```
var data = [
  {name: "Date", value: "12/31/2018", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Car", value: "Ford", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Country", value: "Russia", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Age", value: "20", type: "visible"},
];

var outer = $(".outerPanel");

var createBtns = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
    btn[0].data = data[i];
    var name = data[i].name;
    var value = data[i].value;

    btn.html(name + ": " + value);
    btn.click((e) => btnClick(e));
    outer.append(btn);
  }
}

var btnClick = (e) => {
    var index = data.indexOf(e.currentTarget.data);
    data = data.slice(0,index).concat(data.slice(index+1,data.length));
    e.currentTarget.remove()
}

createBtns();
```

the second approach is just delete the data and re-render the whole thing

```
var data = [
  {name: "Date", value: "12/31/2018", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Car", value: "Ford", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Country", value: "Russia", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Age", value: "20", type: "visible"},
];

var outer = $(".outerPanel");

var createBtns = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
    btn[0].data = data[i];
    var name = data[i].name;
    var value = data[i].value;

    btn.html(name + ": " + value);
    btn.click((e) => btnClick(e));
    outer.append(btn);
  }
}

var btnClick = (e) => {
    var index = data.indexOf(e.currentTarget.data);
    data = data.slice(0,index).concat(data.slice(index+1,data.length));
    outer[0].innerHTML = "";
    createBtns();
}

createBtns();
```

Comment: Yes, $ is JQuery. This and Laurens' answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: And if I'd like to also update `data` array, how would it look like? I mean delete the object from `data` when button disappears.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `const` and `let` (block scoped rather than function scoped), you can simply reference the created `btn` again inside the handler and `.remove()` it in the closure:

```
btn.click(() => btn.remove());
```

```js
const data = [
 {name: "Date", value: "12/31/2018", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Car", value: "Ford", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Country", value: "Russia", type: "visible"},
  {name: "Age", value: "20", type: "visible"},
];

const outer = $(".outerPanel");

const createBtns = () => {
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
    const name = data[i].name;
    const value = data[i].value;

    btn.html(name + ": " + value);
    btn.click(() => btn.remove());
    outer.append(btn);
  }
}

createBtns();
```

```css
.outerPanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerPanel"></div>
```

(without `const` and `let`, you'd have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) instead - still works, but it's a lot uglier)

Comment: And if I'd like to also update `data` array, how would it look like? I mean delete the object from `data` when button disappears.

Comment: Use `.findIndex` to find the index of the item with the same `name` in the `data` array, and then `splice` at that index to remove the item.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like below:

```
var btnClick = (e) => {
    // get index of clicked button relative to parent element
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.target.parentNode.children, e.target);
    // remove data entry in array
    data.splice(index, 1);
    // remove the clicked button
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
}
```

Updated version of [your demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k5srx106/):

```js
var data = [{
        name: "Date",
        value: "12/31/2018",
        type: "visible"
    },
    {
        name: "Car",
        value: "Ford",
        type: "visible"
    },
    {
        name: "Country",
        value: "Russia",
        type: "visible"
    },
    {
        name: "Age",
        value: "20",
        type: "visible"
    },
];

var outer = $(".outerPanel");

var createBtns = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var btn = $('<div class="btn"></div>');
        var name = data[i].name;
        var value = data[i].value;

        btn.html(name + ": " + value);
        btn.click((e) => btnClick(e));
        outer.append(btn);
    }
}

var btnClick = (e) => {
    // get index of clicked button relative to parent element
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.target.parentNode.children, e.target);
    // remove data entry in array
    data.splice(index, 1);
    // refresh displayed text
    refreshText();
    // remove the clicked button
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
}

var refreshText = () => {
    document.getElementById("dataText").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
}

createBtns();
refreshText();
```

```css
.outerPanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerPanel"></div>
<h3>Data array contents</h1>
<p id="dataText"></p>
```

Comment: So easy! It was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: And if I'd like to also update `data` array, how would it look like? I mean delete the object from `data` when button disappears.

Comment: I updated my answer so it includes updating the `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add an event to the button, like this :

```js
 function addHideEvent(element) { 
                     
 for(i=0;i<element.length;i++) { 
  element[i].onclick = function(e) { 
   this.remove()
  }
 }
}
                
addHideEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("btn"))
```

```html
<button class="btn"> CLICK HERE </button>  </br>
<button class="btn"> CLICK HERE </button>  </br>
<button class="btn"> CLICK HERE </button>  </br>
<button class="btn"> CLICK HERE </button>  </br>
```

Comment: I wrote I want to delete it from DOM, not hide with `display`

Comment: @hames Just added this.remove()

Answer (score 0):

### Update

removing the btn from DOM instead of CSS change

## Solution

You can add an event listener to the button when u create it inside the for loop.

## Example code here:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Date",
    value: "12/31/2018",
    type: "button"
  },
  {
    name: "Car",
    value: "Ford",
    type: "button"
  },
  {
    name: "Country",
    value: "Russia",
    type: "button"
  },
  {
    name: "Age",
    value: "20",
    type: "button"
  },
];

const createBtns = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
    btn.setAttribute('value', data[i].value);
    btn.setAttribute('type', data[i].type);
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.body.removeChild(btn)
    });
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
}

createBtns();
```

Comment: I wrote I want to delete it from DOM, not hide with `display`

Comment: I have made the changes. :)