# Make a function that recognises which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a 3 buttons in my HTML, one for each of three ski resorts. When a button is clicked I want to display the relevant information.

```
<div id="buttonParent">
    <button id="btnStranda" type="button" value="0">Stranda</button>
    <button id="btnFjellseter" type="button" value="1">Fjellseter</button>
    <button id="btnOveroeye" type="button" value="2">Overøye</button>
</div>
```

I have this working, but the problem is I've made 3 separate functions which I believe could easily be made into 1.

If all the `onclick` events go to the same function, how do I make the function detect which button was clicked so it will display the correct information?

```
function boot() 
{
    document.getElementById("btnStranda").onclick = infoStranda;
    document.getElementById("btnOveroeye").onclick = infoOveroeye;
    document.getElementById("btnFjellseter").onclick = infoFjellseter;
}
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1BTKDWyn)

Comment: You can add a class to your button when you click it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button)

Comment: Include the content of the functions you’ve written to see what you’re actually trying to achieve with them, what differentiates them, what reuse of logic can be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

When functions get fired via an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), they pass a parameter to the event handler, usually named `event` or `e`, which is the event itself.

[`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached.

```js
document.querySelector('#foo').onclick = doSomething
document.querySelector('#bar').onclick = doSomething


function doSomething(e) {
  // log id of current target element of the click event
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id, ' was clicked')
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
<button id="bar">Bar</button>
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) which refers to the element that fired the event.

Comment: +1 However, I recommend using data attributes instead of the `id` property: `<button data-id="someButton">`. Then, in your click handler you can get the value by using `e.currentTarget.dataset.id`.

Comment: I intentionally used an ID because I assume the OP is familiar with it. Good suggestion though, that's what I do too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that you call with parameters depending on the button clicked. So you still have three distinct functions for the click listener. I think it is better than add some info (class or id) on the DOM nodes to distinct your cases in just one function.

So keep three functions but call a generic function to do the generic things.

So for example :

```
function commonOperation(indexInContact) {
    // make your operations based on the param(s)
}

// And one of your function that listen a click will call common 
function infoStranda() {
    commonOperation(0)
    // Do specific Stranda things if needed
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you could do it.

I would implement **option 1** as its simple and clean, if your using jQuery **option 3** is also not a bad shout.

**Option 1: Add a function and pass object (self) into it**

```js
function displayInfoById(element) {
     console.log(element.value);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonParent">
    <button id="btnStranda" type="button" value="0" onclick="displayInfoById(this)">Stranda</button>
    <button id="btnFjellseter" type="button" value="1" onclick="displayInfoById(this)">Fjellseter</button>
    <button id="btnOveroeye" type="button" value="2" onclick="displayInfoById(this)">Overøye</button>
</div>
```

**Option 2: Using the attached event handler to get the event currentTarget.**

```js
document.getElementById("btnStranda").onclick = displayInfo;
document.getElementById("btnOveroeye").onclick = displayInfo;
document.getElementById("btnFjellseter").onclick = displayInfo;

function displayInfo(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.value)
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonParent">
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnStranda" type="button" value="0">Stranda</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnFjellseter" type="button" value="1">Fjellseter</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnOveroeye" type="button" value="2">Overøye</button>
</div>
```

**Option 3: Using a class attribute with jQuery event handler `.on('click'):`**

```js
$(".buttonClass").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonParent">
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnStranda" type="button" value="0">Stranda</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnFjellseter" type="button" value="1">Fjellseter</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="btnOveroeye" type="button" value="2">Overøye</button>
</div>
```