# Getting the ID from a button created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I am creating a few buttons dynamically via javascript.

```
function dobutton() {
    for (i=0; i<eigenschaften; i++){
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.className = 'button black';
    btn.id = eigenschaftsarray[i];
    btn.name = 'pickbutton';
    btn.innerHTML = eigenschaftsarray[i].split("_").join(" ");
    document.getElementById('auswahl').appendChild(btn);
    document.getElementById('auswahl').innerHTML += " ";
    }
}
```

eigenschaften = 39

eigenschaftsarray = just some names

Now I want to get the ID of the button I click. I was not able to get anything from this [JavaScript - onClick to get the ID of the clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button) running because of my method using js to create those buttons. Adding the onClick event to my code just instantly alerts 39 "unknown".

Can someone provide me some help, I am just using Javascript, no jQuery :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Please add the code which adds the event listeners.

Comment: What to you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create elements dynamically, you have to keep in mind that you can bind events to them only after they are available in the DOM.

Here is a working demo: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xh61sru9/1/)

In the demo, we bind an event listener ("click") to the parent that contains the buttons. The parent is a static element, already available in the DOM.

The JavaScript code is:

```
var eigenschaften = 3;
var eigenschaftsarray = ["b0","b1","b2"];
// fn: detect if a button was clicked -> get id
function buttonClick(e){
  // check if the clicked element is a button
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "button") {
    var btn = e.target;
    // alert the user what button was clicked
    alert("button id="+btn.id);
  }
}
// fn: create buttons dynamically
function dobutton() {
    // identify parent
    var parent = document.getElementById('auswahl');
    // create buttons dynamically
    for (i=0; i<eigenschaften; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.className = 'button black';
        btn.id = eigenschaftsarray[i];
        btn.name = 'pickbutton';
        btn.innerHTML = eigenschaftsarray[i].split("_").join(" ");
        // append btn to parent
        parent.appendChild(btn);
        parent.innerHTML += " ";
    }
    // add "click" listener on parent
    parent.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
}
// create buttons
dobutton();
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for your help! It's working perfectly. The only issue is that my Firefox console gives me _TypeError: parent is null_ for `parent.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);`. Can I ignore that or should that be fixed somehow?

Comment: The answer works. But may I ask why `function buttonClick(e)` has argument `e` but it is not passed in `parent.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);`? I'm just wondering the reason behind this.

Comment: Hi. The JSfiddle is working well. Please check the line: "var parent = document.getElementById('auswahl');" -> here I assume that your HTML already contains an element with an id="auswahl" (I got it from your code). If you get *null* in console => it means that your HTML doesn't have that element OR that you are running the script *before* the page loaded the element. Can you try to create a jsfiddle yourself with your HTML+JS and test it?

Comment: Hi @YuKo - that's how add​Event​Listener works -> it automatically passes to a callback function an *Event* as parameter - check the reference here: [Event​Target​.add​Event​Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)

Comment: @verjas I got the problem; I had the `dobutton()` in my `window.onload` already so the `dobutton()` from your code obviously didn't like that :D

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add Buttons Dynamically To DOM

**HTML** :

```
<body>
    <h1>
        HelloWorld HelloWorld
    </h1>
    <div id="stackMe"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript** :

```
const data = [{'Name' : 'Hello', 'Id' : 1},
               {'Name' : 'World', 'Id' : 2}];
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    console.log('DOM loaded');
    generateButtons(data);
});

function generateButtons(data) {
  const buttonResults = data.map(bt =>`<button id= "${bt.Id}" onClick="btClicked(${bt.Id})">Button ${ bt.Name }</button>`);
  document.getElementById("stackMe").innerHTML = buttonResults;
}
```

**Step 2**: Add an event listener for the button clicked

```
function btClicked(currentId) {
  let elementClicked = data.find(d => d.Id == currentId);
  console.log(elementClicked);
}
```

**Output:** Out after the button is clicked

[image]