# JavaScript onclick event retrieve attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have some 3D shapes on a page (X3DOM) that I would like to identify when clicked with the mouse.
My HTML looks like this :

```html
<Transform translation='0 0 0'> 
                    <shape id="Roger1" number="54 -15 -34" onclick="changeColor();"> 
                        <appearance> 
                            <material diffuseColor='1 0 0'></material> 
                        </appearance> 
                        <sphere>radius='1' </sphere> 
                    </shape> 
                </Transform>
```

Then, in JavaScript, I have the corresponding function set up this way :

```js
function changeColor() {
    window.alert('clicked');
}
```

This works great. But I don't see how I could recover the information contained in the "number" tag, number="54 -15 -34"? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element itself as a parameter to the function:

```js
function changeColor(element) {
    window.alert(element.getAttribute('number'));
}
```

```html
<Transform translation='0 0 0'>
  <shape id="Roger1" number="54 -15 -34" onclick="changeColor(this);">
    <appearance>
      <material diffuseColor='1 0 0'></material>
    </appearance>
    <sphere>radius='1' </sphere>
  </shape>
</Transform>
```

Comment: There was a solution, here, under "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button" which I only found after posting my question -- naturally? --  but I'll go along with your fine suggestion -- thank you so much!