# Reapply style after adding content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I will try to expand my problem:

I have a link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="Display(); return false;">Display</a>
```

I have some styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
 background-color: #AFA99B;
}
</style>
```

And the folowing js code:

```
function printf(MyHtml){
document.write(MyHtml); 
}

function Display(){
printf("<p>some html code<p>");
//...
}
```

So when the user click the link, I must add some html content to the body & the new added elements must use the styles defined.
That's all.

Comment: They *should* do. You seem to have reduced your test case beyond the point where the problem is visible. Please expand it.

Comment: When are you calling this line? If you call it after the document was loaded, it will replace the whole content of the document, also the style definitions. See the difference between [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kqda/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kqda/1/).

Comment: Maybe your CSS is not targeting that `<p>` tag?

Comment: Yea, they do get the style. Something else is the problem.

Comment: your question is wrong. check your code you are doing some kind of mistake

Comment: I tried to expand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem was talking about in my comment. You are calling `document.write(MyHtml)` *after* the document was fully loaded.

It will completely replace the document (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write)). Inspect it, you will see that there is an empty `head` (also see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kqda/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kqda/1/) example).

Use [other methods to manipulate the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/javascript-what-are-alternatives-to-document-write).