# why styles and javascripts code not apply to new added html content

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, yii2

I request to the server with ajax and get a response some HTML code. I get it and add to div which has id='conten' but styles and scripts not apply

this is my ajax request tirgger:

```
  <li class="catalogs"  catalog_id="<?= $category->id?>"><?= $category->title?></li>
```

this is my ajax post:

```
//get catalogs
        $('.catalogs').click(function () {
            let catalog_id = this.getAttribute('catalog_id')
            console.log(catalog_id)

            $.ajax({

                url: '/site/catalog',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    id: catalog_id
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#conten').html(response);
            })

        })
```

this is my action in SiteController

```
    public function actionCatalog($id)
    {
        $products = \common\models\Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $id]);
        $subCategories = \common\models\SubCategory::findAll(['category_id' => $id]);
        return $this->renderAjax('index',[
            'products' => $products,
            'subCategories' => $subCategories,
        ]);
    }
```

and it is my div with id="conten"

```
 <div id="conten">
     <?= $content?>
 </div>
```

my AppAssets files

```
// css
'css/plugins.css',
        'css/style.css',
        'css/responsive.css'
//js

'js/jquery.js',
        'js/plugins.js',
        'js/functions.js'
```

Comment: you talk about the css style but we doesn't have any code, and how do you know the script is not applying ?

Comment: For Javascript events you need to do event delegation. For CSS it does not make any sence why it wouldn't work. Can you please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Not clear what you are expecting, and what's currently happening.

Comment: my css and js code is all libraries

Comment: We don't ask for all your libraries. We ask for a reproducible example. Just a reproduction of your problem with the least amount of code to keep things clear. Since your problem seems to be client side you can easily create a snippet.

Comment: my problem is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991594/reapply-style-after-adding-content-with-javascript

Comment: but the above question's answer is not true. pls help me

Comment: show the css code you have in your css files for the `.catalogs` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load your JS and CSS with ajax? if so, this is because your html page where you include all the css are loaded as the document is ready..it reads all classes and according to the style sheet it applies on that.. but in ajax we load the other page on the same html page and this time browser not map the html classes to the style sheet that is why your css is not applying on that.

There are two ways to do this one is inline css and other one is load all the css files again after the ajax page is loded.. you can do it via jquery or javascript.

Here is the example:
[Is there an easy way to reload css without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024486/is-there-an-easy-way-to-reload-css-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: `$this->renderAjax()` loads the view along with the necessary js and css registered for the view

Comment: Thanks a looooooot . That was exactly what I needed