# How to open a new window and insert html into it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a new window from javascript but nothing is being inserted into the html:

```
var callScriptText = $('#callScriptText').html();
var url = '/Action/CallScript/?callScript=';

// Open the current call script in a new window
var openWindow = window.open(url, 'callScriptPopup', 'width = 500, height = 500');
$(openWindow).html(callScriptText);
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Here's an example to open a new window with content using jQuery

```
<script>
function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();

    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$(function() {
    $("a#print").click(nWin);
});​
</script>

<div id="toNewWindow">
    <p>Your content here</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="print">Open</a>​
```

EDIT:
For those who say that this code doesn't work, here's a jsfiddle to try it http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/

Comment: Thanks that worked! But how do I add a url into it so that it doesn't just say about:blank?

Comment: if you want the URL in the new window just replace the window.open with
`window.open('/Action/CallScript/?callScript=', 'myWin', 'width = 500, height = 500');`
That will load the URL and set that name into the window. Also you can delete the line `var html=$("#toNewWindow").html();`

Comment: Glad to here that. Set my question as OK and my job is done here :)

Comment: Is there any possibility of inserting the hole html (like the following structure instead of putting from the body `<html><head><title></title><script></script><body></body></html>`)

Comment: Sorry Thirumalai, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You can even open the print dialog, too:  
`    function nWin() {
`      var w = window.open();
`      var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();
`    
`        $(w.document.body).html(html);
`        w.print();
`        w.close();
`    }

Answer (score 88):

Try this:

```
var x=window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write('content');
x.document.close();
```

I find it works in Chrome and IE.

Comment: This works better than the jQuery solution because you can write an entire HTML document, including the doctype and `<head>` tags.

Comment: not working in my chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m. The x after window.open() return undefined so it don't have document

Comment: clean and simple solution

Comment: Thanks! @LucVH
Adding to the solution, if your browser block the popup you can check it adding `if(!x) alert('Enable popups please!)`
Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522743/8990184)

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me in Chrome 70 - opens new tab

Answer (score 25):

Building upon @Emre's answer.

With javascript, you can chain, so I just modified the code to:

```
var x=window.open();
x.document.open().write('content');
x.close();
```

Also, to force it to a new window (not a new tab), give the first line dimensions.  But it has to be the third argument.  So change the first line to:

```
var x=window.open('','','width=600, height=600');
```

Comment: That chaining is somewhat too aggressive, document.write() doesn't return anything so Chrome reports: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined.

Comment: @jjrv, that isn't aggressive chaining... you should check first before the chaining... e.g., `if(content!=='undefined'){x.document.open().write(content).close();}`

Comment: document.write() always returns undefined, so the chained code always calls undefined.close() and always throws an error.

Comment: in the good old days the window.open parameters couldnt have spaces neither :P

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
var x = window.open('', '', 'location=no,toolbar=0');
x.document.body.innerHTML = 'content';
```

Comment: Works in chrome 70

Comment: the question specifically asked for a solution using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
var win = window.open('', 'title', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=1000,left=200,top=70');
var codeContents = document.getElementById("contentsfornewWindow").innerHTML;
win.document.body.innerHTML = codeContents;
```

VS:

```
win.document.write(codeContents);
```

I have notice if there are iframes like youtubes videos , `win.document.write` loads the iframes where as `document.body.innerHTML` does not!

Comment: Do you have any idea why? How could one avoid using document.write() but still be able to load resources like images, iframes etc..?

Comment: @D.Petrov this has already been discussed in this thread, hope that help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write