# How to configure JQUERY UI Dialog as a new window ?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQUERYUI Dialog in a popup page. I want this Dialog to be opened as a new window ( like window.open) Is this possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jquery dialog at all, it's just a floating div with higher z-index.

```
<script>
function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $("#toNewWindow").html();

    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$(function() {
    $("a#print").click(nWin);
});​
</script>

<div id="toNewWindow">
    <p>Your content here</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" id="print">Open</a>​
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery)