# How to send the content of a textarea into a new window

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I wanna know how do you send the content of the textarea into a new window by using the Window open() method.

heres is my little code:

HTML

```
 <textarea name="textcode"></textarea>
 <button  type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Open in New window</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("insert the new window path here");
}
```

Comment: `$("textarea[name=textcode]").val();` maybe ?

Comment: Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery)

Comment: What does the new window contain? Only the text? So is this what you want? `'data:text/plain,' + document.querySelector('textarea[name=textcode]').value`

Comment: if i type in <b>hello</b> in the textarea, the new window should have a hello word that is bolded. is it possible ? and by the way where should exacltly put the code? im new in javascript and php

Comment: Please explain how this relates to PHP or remove the "php" tag.

Comment: *How* would you send the textarea content into a new window? What is the document opened in it supposed to contain, and in which sense would you send a string into it?

Comment: is the new window on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

use below code using jquery.

HTML

```
<textarea name="textcode" id="text"></textarea>
<button  type="button" id="openwindow">Open in New window</button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#openwindow').click(function(){
      var value  = $('#text').val();
      window.open('https://www.google.co.in/?#q='+value);
    });
});
```

you can pass value as params.include path and params. you will get value of text area in query string .using PHP $_GET['param'] you will print data in new window.

**using pure javascript**
HTML

```
<textarea name="textcode" id="text"></textarea>
<button  type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Open in New window</button>
```

javascript

```
 function myFunction(){
    var value  = document.getElementById("text").value;
    window.open('https://www.google.co.in/?#q='+value);
 }
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with jquery, and jquery is hardly useful here as compared with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why trying to send data between windows if you can have direct access to the content/DOM of the parent window? This will give you advantages when the content of your textarea is/can be changed. The "child page" will keep a reference to the page that opened it!

parent.html

```
<textarea id="mytext" name="textcode"></textarea>
<button  type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Open in New window</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    //open popup/window on the same domain
    window.open('newwindow.html','newwindow','width=350,height=350');
}
</script>
```

When the new window opens you can have access to it's parents DOM only if they are on the same domain.

In your `newwindow.html` you can access your textarea (or any other DOM element) with `window.opener`:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("mytext").value
```

Like I said, this only works when your parent and child windows are on the same domain. You will run into "[same-origin policy errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)" when parent and child aren't in the same domain.

However! you can use `Window.postMessage` to safely pass data between windows that aren't on the same domain. This isn't supported that well in all browsers.

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

You can find an example and additional information (like browser support etc) on the dev pages of mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)