# Javascript: From current page, open new window at a URL, then manipulate the content of the new window and close the original window

Tags: javascript

This is literally day two in my total JavaScript experience, so please bear with me. I am able to open a new window, no problem. I can direct that window, when opened, to a certain URL. Again, no problem. I just can't seem to manipulate anything on the new window. Here is the code so far: (at the end of the script, I am closing the original window.)

```
var win = window.open("URL",'','channelmode,height=' + 
          window.screen.availHeight + ',width=' + window.screen.availWidth + ',')
var output = "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Close Window\" onclick=\"windowClose();\">"    

//Doesn't work..
win.document.body.innerHTML += output //also tried with just --> ...innerHTML = output
//

//Doesn't work..
win.dataFromParent = output
win.document.body.innerHTML(dataFromParent)
//win doesn't actually have the variable "dataFromParent" defined in the code, and I can't change the page that is loaded to include it, so is that why this isn't working?

//Doesn't work..
win.dataFromParent = output
win.document.body.appendChild(dataFromParent)
//

function windowClose() { 
    window.open('','_parent',''); 
    window.close();
} 
windowClose()  //Done in this manner to prevent the "Page trying to close window..." dialog box
```

There are two things that I am trying to do:

1. On the opened window (win), place a button, at a certain position, that will close the window (win)
2. On the opened window (win), disable the ability of someone being able to double-click the title bar and it changing the window size. (I know the "window.open" has a "resizable" option that can be set to "no" but that doesn't seem to actually work.)

These are the main links that I've used to try and figure out the first task.

[Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000178.htm
[How to open a new window and insert html into it using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

I really don't know how to do the second one...Everywhere that I've looked only has things like that for other languages..

Comment: Is the location of the document you're opening in the popup window on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain.