# Check if element exists in fetched URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web-crawler, window.open

I have a page with, say, 30 URLS, I need to click on each and check if an element exists.
Currently, this means:

```
$('area').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
    var appID = (window.location.href).split('?')[1];
    $(this).attr("href", _href + '?' + appID);
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Which opens 30 new tabs, and I manually go through them.

**(all URLS are in the same domain)**

It would be really nice have a crawler with the following logic:

```
$('area').each(function(){

 1) get the HREF
 2) follow it
 3) on that new page:
    if($('.element')){
     push the $('area') into array1 
    } else {
     push the $('area') into array2
        }
    });


   4) Display array1 in green
      Display array2 in red
```

Basically, Id like to generate a report that says:

X crawled pages **had** element Y

Z crawled pages **did not have** element Y

Im obviously stuck at making Javascript/jQuery work in a newly opened tab.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384) , but Im not entirely sure if this is viable.

Can this be done with Javascript/jQuery?

I'm only **asking for the right direction**, I'll do the steps myself.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you use `iframe` for loading pages.

For example:

```
$.each($your-links, function(index, link) {
    var href = $(link).attr("href");
    // your link preprocess logic ...

    var $iframe = $("<iframe />").appendTo($("body"));
    $iframe.attr("src", href).on("load", function() {
        var $bodyContent = $iframe.contents().find("body");
        // check iframe content and remove iframe
        $iframe.remove();
    }
}
```

But, I should say, if your crawler and checked pages have a different domains there will be the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problems.

I've created a simple project that shows how to implement this approach.
You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rbm6pksp5sqesc/js-crawler.zip?dl=0) and run on some local web-server (apache, iis etc.)