# String html to browser window

Tags: php, html, css

I get string from database dynamically within my website, that contains fully  HTML code,I  need to show this string html to new browser window, suggest me how to do this.

```
<html>
..............
..............
<a href="#">link</a> (when click link it render value from db that contains whole html page, I am already in html page, how to show this extra html page)
..............
..............
</html>
```

note: I know **echo** command used to display html element to browser but my case is different. for example already I have body tag and write css, js, jquery for body tag, when I render html string from db, then used echo, it will add one more body tag to my website, so its get conflict with old one.

Comment: You want to display a page that's of full html inside your database?

Comment: `echo htmlentities($string);`

Comment: @LFlare  Yes, I need to show a page that's of full html inside my  database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted - maybe, this will help you?

Comment: Does the string you are receiving from your database contain a body tag?

Comment: Whole html page that contain css, js, jquery and  body tag

Comment: Raj I strongly suggest you only retrieve the elements you need and place them in different areas of your PHP file.  Store the header,  body and footer separately,  and load them into each separate section.

Answer (score -1):

you can store value in any variable and use echo function

Answer (score -1):

To open your page in a new window, use target="_blank" in your link declaration. This will open your link in a new window or new tab depending on your browser.

i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="new page url" target="_blank">Link to new window</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no url,  only php string variable contain html (its not a file, only variable)

Comment: If you have the url in a php variable you could do something like this to append the variable to your html line.: `<?php echo "<a href='".$string."' target='_blank'>Link to new window</a>"; ?>`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399354/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-insert-html-into-it-using-jquery) to see how to open a new window and insert html using jQuery.