# Can't use document.write more than one time in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my HTML and I call external PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<script src="index.php"></script>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and my PHP Script

```
<?
$strFileName = "poom.bis";
$objFopen = fopen($strFileName, 'r');
if ($objFopen) {
    while (!feof($objFopen)) {
        $file = fgets($objFopen, 4096);
//        echo $file;
        echo "document.writeln('$file'+);";
    }
    fclose($objFopen);
}

$test = "hello world";

echo "document.writeln(
    '<ul>'+
        '<li>.$test.</li>'+
        '<li>test2</li>'+
        '<li>test3</li>'+
    '</ul>'
    );";

?>
```

It error when using document.write more than one time

What should I do to solve this problem

Please Advice

PS. use echo "document.writeln('$file'+);"; for one time there is no error and show a result

Comment: Bottom one is `writeIN`, not `writeLN`. Typo.

Comment: So instead of writting output in the server-side, you send the instruction to write output and the output itself to the client-side? Wouldn't it be easier just to `echo` everything without `document.write`?

Comment: I wonder why everyone that gets an error considers that the error message is not relevant to his problem.

Comment: echo won't make a result appear  @package

Comment: and event I use writeln in still error and It's just wrong typing in the question not in my code @CORRUPT

Comment: @JongzPuangput So you typed the entire code here :O

Comment: well always copy and past your code we need your exact code. show us the error message. anyway you know that everything you write with `document.writeln` is not visible to search engines? so instad of `<script src="index.php"></script>`  you should change your document containing this to an php document and do an `include` there and use `echo`

Comment: You must use `script type="javascript"` before using `document.write`

Comment: Read this thread, too: [What are alternatives to document.write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/javascript-what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Answer (score 0):

First error: your line

```
echo "document.writeln('$file'+);";
```

should be

```
echo "document.writeln('$file');";
```

(without the plus sign). Also make sure that the file `poom.bis` doesn't contain a newline, not even at the end. If it does, you have to strip them away ([`trim()`](http://php.net/trim)).

Second error **was** (until you edited it) the use of `document.writeIn` (which doesn't exist) instead of `document.writeln` (which does).

Tested and it works.

Also, while I'm at it, since you asked for advice how to solve this problem: look at your browser's error console and try to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<script>document.writeln(';
echo '"<ul><li>test1</li><li>test2</li><li>test3</li></ul>"';
echo ');</script>';
;
```

Comment: If you re-read the question carefully, you will see that the PHP file is included as a script file: `<script src="index.php"></script>`.

Comment: Yes you have, but that's not what I meant. Let me try to explain again: The OP has posted 2 code samples, coming from 2 different files. In the first one, the HTML file, you see that the second one (the PHP file) is included via a `<script>` tag. This means that `index.php` should produce valid JavaScript, not HTML. Your answer, however, includes a `<script>` tag being output. This has no business being in a JavsScript file.