# What is the alternative for document.write in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JS code to be executed which contains an unescape function inside document.write method as below.

```
document.write(unescape(''));
```

But, I am not allowed to use document.write method. How to implement this without using document.write ?

Comment: Call the function, assign its output to a variable and set it using `.innerHTML`. Is that what you want? [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/rArgd/)

Comment: what the.. are you trying to do....??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: document.write(unescape('%3Cimg alt="Chat Now" src="' + (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//someurl?0&amp;cbdid=000&amp;wdid=111" border="0" id=' + bccbId + ' /%3E'));
This code I need to execute without using document.write.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way to write directly to the HTML document. But you can always change the content of a container element (for example a DIV, or table CELL) without using document.write, but using for example the [innerHTML DOM property of an element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp):

```
var el = document.getElementById("content");
el.innerHTML = "<b>An example that modifies the HTML document</b>";

<div id="content"></div>
```

Using the code above you can write:

```
el.innerHTML = unescape('...');
```

An answer to the same question and a link to a DOM manipulation tutorial can be found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/javascript-what-are-alternatives-to-document-write).