# Javascript object undefined keyword in the end of output statement

Tags: javascript

I have made an object in javascript its running fine but in the end of every statement it is saying "Undefined".Here's my javascript.

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        function sports(sportsname, country, player, difficulty){
             this.sportsname = sportsname;
             this.country = country;
             this.player = player;
             this.difficulty = difficulty; 
             this.hissportstaste = sportstaste;
        }

        var Cricket = new sports("Cricket", "Pakistan", "Shahid Afridi", "Difficult");
        var Football = new sports("Football", "Spain", "David Villa", "Difficult");
        var Tennis = new sports("Tennis", "Switzerland", "Roger Federer", "Difficult");

        function sportstaste(){
            if(this.country == "Pakistan"){
                document.write(this.player + " Is the best and he is a " + this.sportsname + " Player");
            }
            if(this.country == "Spain"){
                document.write(this.player + " Is the best and he is a " + this.sportsname + " Player");
            }
            if(this.country == "Switzerland"){
                document.write(this.player + " Is the best and he is a " + this.sportsname + " Player");
            }
        }
        document.write(Cricket.hissportstaste());
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write(Football.hissportstaste());
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write(Tennis.hissportstaste());
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    </script>
```

And the output that its giving is.

```
Shahid Afridi Is the best and he is a Cricket Playerundefined
David Villa Is the best and he is a Football Playerundefined
Roger Federer Is the best and he is a Tennis Playerundefined
```

I am expecting this output.

```
Shahid Afridi Is the best and he is a Cricket Player
David Villa Is the best and he is a Football Player
Roger Federer Is the best and he is a Tennis Player
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
document.write(Football.hissportstaste());
```

to

```
Football.hissportstaste();
```

and the same for the similar calls : your functions returns nothing (`undefined`) and already writes to the document.

But you should try to completely avoid `document.write`, this functions has very specific uses ([it can't be used once the document is loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes)), you should learn to change the DOM instead (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write) for example).