# Function Defined but still getting not defined

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, increment, stopwatch

I am trying to make a stop watch in js and my code is working correctly until I include Millisecond in my stopwatch.

Here's my code:

## index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Second Page</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="gettime()" value="Start Stopwatch"></a>
    </body>

</html>
```

## script.js

```
 var ss = 0,
    mm = 0,
    hh = 0,
    ms = 0;
var once = 0;

function gettime() {
    if (once == 0) {
        document.write('<h1 id="stopwatch"></h1>');
        once++;
    }
    setInterval("msss()", 100);
}

function msss() {   // I have defined msss

    printtime();
    if (ms > 1000) {
        sec();
    } else {
        ms += 100;
    }

}

function sec() {
    ms = 0;
    printtime();
    if (ss > 59) {
        min();
    } else {
        ss += 1;
    }
}

function min() {
    ss = 0;
    printtime();
    if (mm > 59) {
        hr();
    } else {
        mm += 1;
    }
}

function hr() {

    mm = 0;
    printtime();
    hh += 1;
}

function printtime() {
    document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = 'H: ' + hh + 'M: ' + mm + ' S: ' + ss + ' MS: ' + ms;
}
```

**Error Code**

> ReferenceError: msss is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldnt be setInterval(msss, 100); ?

Comment: @BOSS Thanks it works, But it doesn't works on Firefox 30.0 . Please help

Comment: Your `setInterval` call should look like this: `setInterval(msss, 100)`

Comment: Is that an input element closed with `</a>` ?

Comment: And, the code posted works just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0r2tpt77/**, as noted passing strings to `setInterval` is bad practice, but shouldn't break anything.

Comment: @adeneo +1 for pointing that mistake!

Comment: `setInterval("msss()", 100);` is bad practice.  Passing a string, makes it use `eval`, which you should not do.  Use `setInterval(msss, 100);`. Also, don't use `document.write`.  Use `document.body.innerHTML` instead.  `document.write` will trash your entire page (erase it) and replace it with the string.  It might've removed your JavaScript, thus causing the problem.

Comment: @adeneo: Chrome handles `document.write()` differently than Firefox.  Open that JSFiddle in Firefox.  (Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398255)

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yeah, `document.write` is always a bad idea, I only tested it quickly in Chrome, and it worked, but there where *many* things that could be improved.

Comment: @RocketHazmat  I am writing this for personal use, So its ok? right?

Comment: @AsheshKumar: I wouldn't suggest it.  It's better to learn and use the correct practices always, than to get lazy on a simple project.  That will help you do it the right way when it really does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `document.write()`.  It's a bad practice to use this.  What happens is, when this is called, the page is *fully erased*, and replaced with the code.

This removes *everything* on your page, including the JavaScript.  So, `mss` no longer exists, since you just deleted it.

This was explained on an answer to a previous question of yours (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25398255).

Try something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<h1 id="stopwatch"></h1>';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
setInterval(msss, 100);
```

That will execute your msss function every 100 miliseconds. Right now, you're passing in a string and not a function.

Comment: Thanks it works, But it doesn't works on Firefox 30.0 . Please help

Comment: Technically, passing `setInterval("msss()", 100);` works just fine, as it's eval'ed.