# Call combo box value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use the selected combo box item as a variable for the use of javascript image calling?

HTML

```
<select id="fileType">
 <option value=".jpg">.JPG</option>
 <option value=".png">.PNG</option>
 <option value=".gif">.GIF</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var selectedComb = document.getElementById("fileType");
var selectedFileType = selectedComb.options[selectedComb.selectedIndex];
var selectedType = selectedFileType.value;

document.write('<img src="example.com/images/pic + 'selectedType'"/>');
```

Now, obviously this doesn't work. How can I make it work? Its really just the document.write line that needs to be fixed.

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. If you have one then it is constructed with a pile of JavaScript and the answer depends on that JavaScript. Alternatively, you might have meant "a select element" (which is all you have shown). Which is it?

Comment: "Now, obviously this doesn't work" — Why obviously? What behaviour do you get? What behaviour do you expect? What error messages are reported in your JavaScript console?

Comment: It *looks* like you just need to pay more attention to where you are putting your double and single quote characters.

Comment: Sorry, yes, a select element. ( I guess I called it that because in the webpage it looks like one.. or a drop down menu). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Quentin, obviously because ive posted here! haha. Im using Aptana IDE and it in Chrome's console it says the error is on that line. "Unexpected String". 


I just need to know how to make it get the selected item value and plug it into the src url so it makes a full url like "example.com/images/pic.jpg"

Comment: The first set of apostrophes are to call the line. the quotation is to call the src and then in that is another apostrophe to call the variable?

Comment: Apostrophes delimit string literals. You also have a variable with a string in it. `+` concatenates strings together. Look at where you should have string literals and where you should have string variables.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice you should probably be using `document.createElement instead`

Comment: that was just an example. If i were to put the url string part into a variable. and `+` them together.. it still wouldnt work. I tried it.

Comment: @andrew , i tried that, too. It didnt work because thats not the problem. The problem is binding them together into one string.

Comment: well. as @Quentin says looks like you got your concatenation operator(s) wrong the string should be `'<img src="example.com/images/pic'+selectedType+'"/>'`

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Thank you @Quentin and andrew for pointing it out.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398255/2333214) might help.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good thread. This problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) to insert content on the fly while document is being loaded.

According to [MDN's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes):

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open) will automatically perform a [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open) call

And from [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open#Notes):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it

So, Using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the document is loaded will overwrite (*or clear*) your document. For such reasons, [using `document.write()` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/2333214).

Using

```
document.body.innerHTML+= '<img src="example.com/images/pic' +selectedType+ '"/>';
```

instead will fix the issue.

See also [What are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)