# Avoid document.write? Any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am currently using document.write to inject html into my framework. I'm using Backbone, Marionette, require.js, jQuery.

I want to avoid using document.write since it has performance and browser impacts.

Please suggest an alternative.

My current code:

```
    var html = this.compilePageHtml(); //We get some HTML code
    this._previewWindow = window.open("about:blank", "PreviewWindow","width=320, height=570, scrollbars=yes" ); 
    this._previewWindow.document.write(html); //Loads HTML in new window popup
```

Comment: why not use `.html()` instead?..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are alternatives to document.write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: In jQuery:  $(this._previewWindow.document).html(html);

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `.innerHTML` property on the body of the new window.

```
this._previewWindow = window.open("about:blank", "PreviewWindow","width=320, height=570, scrollbars=yes" ); 
this._previewWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g9e8rg7h/

Comment: This replace html in the body element, while it should be document.

Comment: @MaxZoom - it depends upon what the OP's html is (which they don't disclose).  A new window/document is given a skeleton body so this code will set the body HTML.  Yes, you could set the `document.documentElement` HTML too.

Comment: I added `this._previewWindow.document.close();` it loads instantaneously (instead of ~4-5 seconds lag) but I get error loading page by jquery.mobile . This is the div  `<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-verbose ui-loader-textonly"><span class="ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>Error Loading Page</h1></div>` everything seems to be working fine but I don't get why I'm having that error.