# Can't access data from meta tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the data which I am storing in `<meta>` tags using javascript, but for some reason the getAttribute() function is not working.

```js
document.write("<p>")
document.write("Hello, world")
document.write("</p>")

var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta[id="candidate1"]');
metatags.getAttribute("data-candidate")
document.write(metatags)
```

```html
Here is my code:

<body>
  <h1>Testing 1, 2</h1>
  <meta id="candidate1" data-candidate="1">
  <meta id="candidate2" data-candidate="2">
</body>
```

The error produced is "Uncaught TypeError: metatags.getAttribute is not a function"

Does anyone know why this is not working or if there is a better way of accessing the data stored in the tag?

I am a complete novice to javascript so appreciate any tips you can give me.

Comment: Have you tried putting your script tag inside body tag?

Comment: `var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta[id="candidate1"]');` this line is wrong. You should use **query selector** to select by attribute.

Comment: To expand on Ronit's answer - `document.querySelector('meta[id="candidate1"]')` or alternatively `document.getElementById('candidate1')`

Comment: To add to the previous 2 comments, `getElementsByTagName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which does not have a `getAttribute` method, not an element which does. If using `getElementsByTagName`, you have to access each element to query it's attributes. Also, `getElementsByTagName` only expects a tag name, not a selector string.

Comment: When and where is that JS run? Is it in a `<script>` tag in the body of the document? Is it inside a function that gets called by your page? If it's in a function there are bigger problems with his code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta[id="candidate1"]');` this line is **wrong**. You should use **querySelector** to select by attribute.

```js
document.write("<p>")
document.write("Hello, world")
document.write("</p>")

var metatags = document.querySelector('meta[id="candidate1"]');
var candidate = metatags.getAttribute("data-candidate");
document.write(metatags);
document.write("<br /> Candidate -", candidate,"<hr />");


//If you want the values of both then use this code
var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(metatags, function(metaTag) {
  var candidate = metaTag.getAttribute("data-candidate");
  document.write("<br /> Candidate -", candidate);
});
```

```html
Here is my code:

<body>
  <h1>Testing 1, 2</h1>
  <meta id="candidate1" data-candidate="1">
  <meta id="candidate2" data-candidate="2">
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do this! This is a very very bad practice!**

`<meta>` tags are [used for different things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). They control the document (charset, viewport, RSS feed, etc), gives additional information about the page (social-media attributes, author, next page for robots, etc). User data and settings that you want to read from JavaScript shouldn't go here. There is way to pass any data to JS: put a script inside `<head>`, and set some global variables to anything you just want:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var candidate1 = 1;
        var candidate1 = 2;
    </script>
    <script src="your.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can easy access those values from `your.js`:

```
console.info(candidate1, candidate2);
```

As you can see, `<meta>` tags aren't needed. This gives more semantics to your code.

---

To your question:

You might read about [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). The first is used to get all elements where the HTML tag name matches, the other is used with a CSS-like richer selector to get elements. You can't mix these. Hence, probably your `metatags` was null, so you could not call `getAttribute` on it.

Be careful [using `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531116/2625561)! For debugging, use [`window.console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console). In real products, you should never use `document.write`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The reason I was using the meta tag in the way I did was because I'm building my web app using Django (python's web framework) and planned to save a value from jinja (a templating language) in the data-candidate attribute. My understanding was that jinja and javascript didn't work very well together, so was looking for a way to sort this in the html instead.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code I was able to get the data you're looking for.

```
var metatags = document.getElementById('candidate1');
metatags.getAttribute("data-candidate");
```

See here:

```js
document.write("<p>");
document.write("Hello, world");
document.write("</p>");

var metatags = document.getElementById('candidate1');
metatags = metatags.getAttribute("data-candidate");
document.write(metatags);
```

```html
Here is my code:

<body>
  <h1>Testing 1, 2</h1>
  <meta id="candidate1" data-candidate="1">
  <meta id="candidate2" data-candidate="2">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
        var data=metatags[0].getAttribute("data-candidate")
        document.write(data)
```

Comment: Saying "try this" is not helpful even if it solves the problem; you should try to explain the problem and the solution.