# Alternative methods to getElementById and Document.write

Tags: javascript

I am making a function that needs to use a for loop to output all numbers  between two numbers. If the user chooses `1` and `4`, my function would output `1,2,3,4`. Although I have my function working just as I needed it to, the output using `document.GetElementById` doesn't want to co-operate (only overwrites final answer(4)), and `document.write()` takes me to another page which I don't want. What I need is a method that replaces my p id='replaceOne' which puts all the numbers on the same page. Thank you!

```js
function Counter() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  for (i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
    var answer1 = [i];
    document.write(answer1);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      For Loops excercise 1
    </title>
  </head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top">
<p class=headerOne><h3>Counter a</h3>
<textarea id="number1" class="box"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="number2" class="box"></textarea><br>
<button type="button" onclick="Counter()">Find range</button><br>
<p>Your result is: </p>
<p id="replaceOne"></p>
      </td>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"and `document.write()` takes me to another page"_ - No, it just overwrites the current page -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: Why not assemble the whole string `'1,2,3,4'` and write it in a single statement? Put the numbers in an array, say `nums`, and then use `nums.join(',')`

Comment: I'm not seeing where you need an alternative to `getElementById`...

Comment: I need all my numbers to be replaced with my id="replaceOne", basically I need all the numbers to be placed underneath "your result is:". My issue is that document.GetElementById = answer1; gives me only the final listed number (1-4 would give me only 4), and document.write() as stated overwrites the whole page. I need an answers to stay on the same page and list all the numbers! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function with short name which do something same as `document.getElementById` and add it to `innerHTML` of element.
**Function**: `const elm = id => document.getElementById(id)`. This line is just an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) element with id provided to that function. It is same as

```
function elm(id){
    return document.getElementById(id)
}
```

**Updating innerHTML**:
`elm('replaceOne')` returns an element. Every element has a property [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). In this case the `innerHTML` is `''`. I am using Addition Assignment to add the `i` to existing `innerHTML`. The line `elm('replaceOne').innerHTML += i;` is same as

```
elm('replaceOne').innerHTML = elm('replaceOne').innerHTML + i;
```

```js
const elm = id => document.getElementById(id)
function Counter() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  for (i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
    var answer1 = [i];
    elm('replaceOne').innerHTML += i;
  }
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top">
<p class=headerOne><h3>Counter a</h3>
<textarea id="number1" class="box"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="number2" class="box"></textarea><br>
<button type="button" onclick="Counter()">Find range</button><br>
<p>Your result is: </p>
<p id="replaceOne"></p>
      </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay so this worked for me! However, I don't understand the following two lines; const elm = id => document.getElementById(id)                                                         elm('replaceOne').innerHTML += i;                                                                                   Could you please explain the purpose of the two lines, as in my class we've never worked with "= id => document.getElementById(id)" and "+= i;"

Comment: @SAI PALADUGU I have explained a little and added some some for your understanding. Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example of showing me the full function for the arrow function really helped to interpret its use. Also, your explanation for the second part was just what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SAI PALADUGU accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Where is that option :/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question but sounds like you're just looking for something like this?

```js
const $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id) },
      counter = function() {
        let answer = [],
            number1 = $('number1').value,
            number2 = $('number2').value;
        for (i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
          answer.push(i);        
        }
        $('replaceOne').innerHTML = answer;
      };
      
      
// Or es6 is nice too, or can make this whole thing even smaller;
// but for the sake of simple example, not shown here.
```

```html
<h3>Counter</h3>
<textarea id="number1" class="box"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="number2" class="box"></textarea><br>
<button type="button" onclick="counter()">Find range</button><br>
<p>Your result is: <strong id="replaceOne"></strong></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Tip: Don't use $ as a variable name because it may confuse a beginner to js :/ However, I understand your method.

Comment: @SAIPALADUGU actually that was intentional because it's the same use case I the majority of what jquery's usage ends up being (though most of the time jquery is never necessary). So it was more of a mimic reference. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using document.getElementById is the right way to do this.
You try to write it inside the for loop, that why you have only the first item.
You should concatenate your result in a string and set it after your loop