# Document.write created script does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, document.write

I have a finished JQuery for moving a 360° object (picture) with mouse actions.

The code is working:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>jQuery j360 Plugin Demo</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/j360.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
<h1 style="margin-top: 150px;">jQuery j360 Plugin Demo</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#product').j360();
            });
</script>
<center>
<div id="product" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; overflow: hidden;"> 
<img src="v/1.png" /> 
<img src="v/2.png" /> 
<img src="v/3.png" /> 
<img src="v/4.png" /> 
<img src="v/5.png" /> 
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The needed pictures are received on demand from a server, so I have to create this code on demand after receiving the pictures. I use therefore document.write commands - I know they are not best practice, but usually it works ... Anyway this is the code I use - basically the same (even when I'm debugging I can't find a difference in the created HTML to the "original" HTML)

So basically it's like that:

```
<button id="click1" onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.writeln('<html>');
document.writeln('<head>');
document.writeln('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">');
document.writeln('<title>jQuery j360 Plugin Demo</title>');
document.write('<scr');
document.write('ipt src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></scr');
document.write('ipt>');
document.write('<scr');
document.write('ipt type="text/javascr');
document.write('ipt" src="js/j360.js" ></scr');
document.writeln('ipt>');
document.writeln('</head>');
document.writeln('<body>');
document.writeln('<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>');
document.write('<scr');
document.writeln('ipt type="text/javascript">');
document.write('            jQuery(document).ready(func');
document.writeln('tion() {');
document.write("                jQuery('");
document.write('#');
document.writeln("product').j360();");
document.writeln('            });');
document.write('</scr');
document.writeln('ipt>');
document.writeln('<center>');
document.writeln('<div id="product" style="width: 960px; height: 540px; overflow: hidden;">'); 
document.write('<img src="images/01.jpg" />');
document.write('<img src="images/02.jpg" />');
document.write('<img src="images/03.jpg" />');
document.writeln('</div>');
document.writeln('</center>');
document.writeln('</body>');
document.writeln('</html>');
}
</script>
```

The created HTML shows the picture but the jQuery plugin is not working. The JS are the same.

Thank for your help!

Comment: jesus lol, why you need that many document.writes? How can you even read that

Comment: jQuery 1.4.4? `<center>`? Just whoa

Comment: `document.write('</scr'); document.writeln('ipt>');` ???

Comment: As you say, using `document.write` (and its ilk) is recommended against, precisely because it does not just work. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Comment: There are a number of posts on Stack Overflow regarding the disadvantages of `document.write`, including the canonical [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552) I suggest reading the answers to that question.

Comment: @NinoFiliu [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236073/215552)

Comment: As far as what to use instead, take a gander at [What are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4537963/215552).

Comment: *The needed pictures are received on demand from a server* Please precise

Comment: yes you have to break the script tags, otherwise it won't work ... but it seems like nobody can help with these ancient code style :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` overwrites any code you have.

Example:

```js
function overwrite() {
  document.write("Oops, I've overwritten the code!");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <button onclick="overwrite()">Click me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```