# I don't know how to store input from document.write in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, input, document.write

I asked for input on the name of a team because I am trying to create a program that will create a table based on point scores. I have to write my input code in JS because it is within an OnClick Function. I don't, however, understand how to store the user input (in a variable or otherwise.)

I've tried methods such as storing the actual document.write in a variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Soccer Table Generator</h1>
<h3>How Many Teams Would You Like?</h3>

<select id="num_of_teams">
    <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<script>
var menu = document.getElementById("num_of_teams");
menu.addEventListener("change", generateData);

function generateData(event) {
  if (menu.value == '2') {
    alert("You have selected 2 teams. Would you like to proceed?");
    document.write ("What is the name of your first team?");
    var teamone = document.write ("<input type = 'text' value = 
'input here'<input>");
document.write ("What is the name of your second team?");
  } else if (menu.value == '3') {
    alert("You have selected 3 teams. Would you like to proceed?");

  } else if (menu.value == '4') {
    alert("You have selected 4 teams. Would you like to proceed?");
  }

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I would expect for the input to be stored in a variable and printed (when I used the code for it to be printed), but when I try that it shows up undefined.

Comment: Forget that document.write exists, it is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple way to get user input, you can use [`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt). For example:

```
let first_team = prompt("What is the name of your first team?");
```