# Attach script tag code to dom element for execution , alternate for document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

```
var str = '&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;';
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(str).text();


 //document.write(decoded); THIS WORKS, but I want to avoid using document.write

var para = document.createElement("script");
var node = document.createTextNode(decoded);
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

[jsfiddle.net/1bz9mL7k/2](https://jsfiddle.net/1bz9mL7k/2)

The problem is that due to presence of script tag, this createElement method won't work. Closing script tag in the  encoded str will cause syntax error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<').
Document.write works all perfect but I want to avoid due to its disadvantages of parser-block etc.

In real use case, the encoded string will be of some ads which will be entered by users. Please note we can't remove script tags from code they enter and are saving it in database by using htmlentities($adcode).

User input is trusted, so no issue of any xss vulnerability which might happen by solution proposed.

One of the sample user input :

```
            <script async="async" src="someURL.js"></script>
            <script>
            var googletag = googletag || {};
            googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
            </script>
            <div id="xyzid">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.pubads().display("Mobile_ATF_300x250", [300,250],"div-gpt-ad-0");
            });
            </script>
            </div>
```

There can be various different version of ad set with unknown pattern.

Additional not so relevant info : We will be further using something like `<script>` if(var==1) { codeblock1 } else { codeblock2} `</script>` (here codeblock is 1st code blockset). So any soln which includes use decoded user input directly won't be useful as the script block will break in if-else.

Comment: Can you share a https://jsfiddle.net/, codePen or something with an example ?.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1bz9mL7k/1/ I can't replicate the exact ad code as it won't run on jsfiddle, but this dummy example will be able to display current issue.

Comment: Should you not resolve this on the server side, and just spit out the HTML as a response to an HTTP request?

Comment: @pulkit8 Solved, wish that helps you ! .

Comment: @Carlos1232 not exactly, I replied to your answer

Comment: @trincot yes, that was already in place but due to some modification, now it has to be done using javascript and on client side.

Comment: [What's wrong with `.innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531116/215552)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey innerHTML will add the script code but it won't be executed. Tried already but failed.

Comment: @pulkit8 Guess that I finilly do it without document.write. Wish this helps you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by below code, thought to update if someone in future is stuck on the same problem.

```
var ad = "whatever encoded here script code";

function decodeHtml(html) {
            return $("<textarea/>").html(html).text();
        }

function fetch(id, html) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(id);  
  elm.innerHTML = html;  
  var scripts = elm.getElementsByTagName("script");
  var scriptsClone = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    scriptsClone.push(scripts[i]);
  }
  
for (var i = 0; i < scriptsClone.length; i++) {
    var currentScript = scriptsClone[i];
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    // Copy all the attributes from the original script
    for (var j = 0; j < currentScript.attributes.length; j++) {
      var a = currentScript.attributes[j];
      s.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
    }
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentScript.innerHTML));
    currentScript.parentNode.replaceChild(s, currentScript);
  }
}

var decoded = decodeHtml(ad);
fetch('YourDivID',decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

So for answering this question I had to change first the ad2 since it had inside the script tag, wich is no longer necessary,what you can do is to create an element called Script, of type text/javascript and insert the text, then insert it into the body.

```
var ad2 = `alert(12)`;
var decoded = decodeHtml(ad2);
decoded = decoded.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'')
var para = document.createElement("script");
para.type = "text/javascript";
para.text = decoded
var element = document.getElementById("div12")
element.appendChild(para)
```

Here's a working demo in jsfiddle on how to do It.

https://jsfiddle.net/59g24do1/

**EDIT**
For multiples scripts use this instead; what we do here is first we create an array of the tags,after that we create one by one with the previous function, doing a for loop in order to execute them all. = >

```
function getParagraphs(htmlString) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
  
  return Array.from(div.querySelectorAll("script"))                 
              .map(script => script.outerHTML);
}


for(let i = 0;i<decoded.length;i++){
  if(decoded[i].includes("src")){   
            let srcString = decoded[i].match('src="(.*)"')
        var para = document.createElement("script");
        let aux = decoded[i].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'')
        para.type = "text/javascript";
        para.src = srcString[1]
        para.text = aux
        var element = document.getElementById("div12")
        element.appendChild(para)
  }else{
        let aux = decoded[i].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'')
        let para = document.createElement("script");
      para.type = "text/javascript";
      para.text = aux
      let element = document.getElementById("div12")
            element.appendChild(para)
  }
        
  }
```

For complete example use there's a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/f2Leu74g/2/

Comment: var ad2 = alert(12); This thing is problem. The variable will have script tags i.e <script> alert(12) </script> We can't remove/strip that. The presence of script tag is the main issue. I hope you understood the problem I am facing.

Comment: Okey, I eddited the jsfiddle in onder to fix it; its a simple replace witch regex

Comment: That works, however it fails if we have "multiple script" tags inside that variable. I edited ad variable value with 2 script tags https://jsfiddle.net/dfoxpqre/3/
The use case if for ad set, which have even more then 3 script tags, including some script tags for inclusion of thier js eg  <script async="true" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script> <script> some more ad codes </script>

Comment: In my question "One of the sample user input :" will explain what kind of real user input will look like. It's mixture of multiple script dats, div tags too.  Document.write executes as needed, however looking for its alternative due to drawbacks of it.

Comment: thank you @carlos1232 , I was able to resolve by an alternate soln. posted below. However, I will check your code too so integrate which ever performs best. If you have insights on comparsion do share :)