# How I can call my Javascript function from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can try to get my Javascript output. if I write only 1 function I can, But if I would write 2 or more function, how I can get output of function which I want?

JS File:

```
var time = new Date();
var currenthour = time.getHours();
var welcome;

if(currenthour<=12)
welcome = 'Good Morning';
else if(currenthour >=12 && currenthour <= 17)
welcome = 'Good Afternoon';
else if(currenthour >= 17 && currenthour <= 24)
welcome = 'Good Evening';
document.write(welcome);
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WinMachines</title>
<link rel = "shortcut icon" type= "image/png" href="images\logo.png">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href= "css/style.css">

</head>
<body background="images/lg.jpg">
<h2></h2>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [javascript - What are alternatives to document.write? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Comment: (that having said, if you just want to see the output, just `console.log` is t. Or use Node.js.)

Comment: @user202729 at html file?) I want to get outpur at html file, and I have written to or more function at js file. How I can choose output which I want

Comment: You don't get output "at HTML file". You want the output on the document. Read that link. `document.write` is very likely to be the problem here.

Comment: I want to see output on HTML file, but how I dont know

Comment: Read the linked question and answers there.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple functions in your JS file and you want to call a specific one you should be able to do so by calling that function out in another set of `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function_1();
</script>
<script>
    function_2();
</script>
```

etc. I've done this before and it has worked for me.

Comment: I have to write this at HTML file yes?

Comment: Yes you can add the <script> tags in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` for modifying existing elements. Instead use DOM element selector methods like `document.getElementById` (if the element has a unique `id`), or the more modern `document.querySelector(cssSelectorString)` which will return the first match in the `document`.

```js
const time = new Date();
const currenthour = time.getHours();
let welcome;

if (currenthour <= 12)
  welcome = 'Good Morning';
else if (currenthour >= 12 && currenthour <= 17)
  welcome = 'Good Afternoon';
else if (currenthour >= 17 && currenthour <= 24)
  welcome = 'Good Evening';
  
document.querySelector('h2').textContent = welcome;
```

```html
<h2></h2>
```