# Javacript [ document.write ("___"); ] Shortcut to not start each line with document.write (" or some alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code I want to insert some HTML and normal text in JavaScript and don't want it to always enter document.write(" in starting of each line like this:

```
document.write ("<Style>");
document.write ("html {height:100%}");
document.write (".header {background-color: Aliceblue}");
document.write ("</Style>");

document.write ("<Div class='header'>Website Name</div>");
document.write ("<P style='color:red'>Some text i gathered here</p>");
```

It'll be very helpful if someone could solve this problem or give me some alternative.

Comment: Use it only once... and within the parenthesis, use the backtiks ` instead of double quotes to have multiple lines.

Comment: Not that it matters, but it will with some frameworks, native dom element tags are *always* lowercased.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write `document.write` is stronly discouraged.

Comment: This line doesnt even work, as in breaks syntax `document.write ("<Div class="header">Website Name</div>");` because you use the same nested quote char.

Comment: @DieterRaber it is strongly discouraged, than can you give me some kind of alternative or something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write

Answer (score 1):

1. You can write all at once using ``:

```
document.write(`
  <style>
    html {height:100%}
    .header {background-color: Aliceblue}"
  </style>

  <div class="header">Website Name</div>
  <p style="color:red">Some text i gathered here</p>
`)
```

2. You can create function for it and call it where you need it:

```
<script>
  function write(data) {
    document.write(data)
  }
</script>

...

<script>
  write("<style>");
  write("html {height:100%}");
  ...
</script>
```

Warning:

- write tags names in lowercase:

```
<Style> -> wrong
<style> -> ok
```

- Don't use same quotes inside and outside of string:

```
"<div class="header">Website Name</div>" -> err
"<div class='header'>Website Name</div>" -> ok
```

Comment: OP never explains how his/her nested same quote chars do not produce a syntax error.

Comment: I was surprised too

Comment: I was surprised, but then decided not to be. Debugging multiple issues here with OP.

Comment: I wrote it wrong in the question my mistake.

Comment: @Mero Can't we write <style> or <Style> however we like?

Comment: nope, because in some case it could lead to error or other problems, all tags names should be lowercase

Comment: (+1 mero) tags have to be lowercased because thats the convention. You could technically do what you want tho, they are case-insensitive. However, doesn't explain your nested same quote chars?

Comment: you really don't like same quotes nesting, aren't you ?)