# Why is output value shown as NaN

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, frontend, nan

The code is supposed to find the sum of two times entered in hours and minutes but it gives me the output "NaN".

```js
function add() {
  var min, hrs;
  let a = Number(document.getElementById("first"));
  let b = Number(document.getElementById("third"));
  let c = Number(document.getElementById("second"));
  let d = Number(document.getElementById("fourth"));
  min = c + d;
  hrs = min / 60;
  min = min % 60;
  hrs = hrs + a + b;
  document.write(hrs);
  document.write(min);
}
```

```html
<h1>Time Calculator</h1>
<h2>This calculator can be used to “add” two time values.</h2>
Enter hours: <input id="first"> 
Enter Minutes: <input id="second"> 
Enter hours: <input id="third"> 
Enter Minutes: <input id="fourth">
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the text of your post; links can break.

Comment: i tried to but it showed some indentation error

Comment: I think you have a typo:  min = min%60

Comment: `Number` already creates a number. Calling `value` on a number returns `undefined`.

Comment: @DaveNewton that was in the original code it was like this from the beginning i browsed some sites and added it later. forgot to remove while posting here even without that the answer is same

Comment: @JimVanPetten no man it's not a typo i guess..

Comment: Now you're attempting to create a number out of an element rather than the element's text value. It might also be a good idea to write the answer to an element rather than using `document.write`.

Comment: Also see this related question: [What are alternatives to document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537963/what-are-alternatives-to-document-write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing value calls on the `getElementById`s! So:

```
  let a = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
  let b = Number(document.getElementById("third").value);
  let c = Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
  let d = Number(document.getElementById("fourth").value);
```

Quick recommendation: Add `type="number"` to the inputs to ensure that the inputs are numbers.

```
<h1>Time Calculator</h1>
<h2>This calculator can be used to “add” two time values.</h2>
Enter hours: <input id="first" type="number"> 
Enter Minutes: <input id="second" type="number"> 
Enter hours: <input id="third" type="number">  
Enter Minutes: <input id="fourth" type="number">
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```

Full code:

```
function add() {
  var min, hrs;
  let a = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
  let b = Number(document.getElementById("third").value);
  let c = Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
  let d = Number(document.getElementById("fourth").value);
  min = c + d;
  hrs = min / 60;
  min = min % 60;
  hrs = hrs + a + b;
  document.write(hrs);
  document.write(min);
}
```

Comment: still not working man...

Comment: Try the full function on the edit I just made. I got this working on a codepen: https://codepen.io/Chanodev/pen/yLqXqga. Try adding just 2s.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can easily debug your code line by line with just the browser

[image]

---

and you will realize that, calling

```
document.getElementById("fourth")
```

will return a node, but you are wrapping it up with `Number()`

and then, you are calling `.value` from the `Number()` output

what you could do instead would be, for example

```
        function getNumber(str) {
            return Number(document.getElementById(str).value);
        }
        function add() {
            var min, hrs;
            let a = getNumber("first");
            let b = getNumber("third");
            let c = getNumber("second");
            let d = getNumber("fourth");
            min = c + d;
            hrs = min / 60;
            min = min % 60;
            hrs = hrs + a + b;
            document.write(hrs);
            document.write(min);
        }
```

live example

```js
function getNumber(str) {
    return Number(document.getElementById(str).value);
}
function add() {
  var min, hrs;
  let a = getNumber("first");
  let b = getNumber("third");
  let c = getNumber("second");
  let d = getNumber("fourth");
  min = c + d;
  hrs = min / 60;
  min = min % 60;
  hrs = hrs + a + b;
  document.write(hrs);
  document.write(min);
}
```

```html
<h1>Time Calculator</h1>
<h2>This calculator can be used to “add” two time values.</h2>
Enter hours: <input id="first"> 
Enter Minutes: <input id="second"> 
Enter hours: <input id="third"> 
Enter Minutes: <input id="fourth">
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```