# Embedding a PHP page in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, embed

I want to use Javascript to embed a PHP page into HTML. How do I do that?

The PHP page is [this one](http://www.oddsnavigator.eu/all_matches_baby_goal.php/)
and I'd like it to serve as a widget which can be added on various websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could embed it in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.oddsnavigator.eu/all_matches_baby_goal.php/">
    <a href="http://www.oddsnavigator.eu/all_matches_baby_goal.php/">View matches</a>
</iframe>
```

The inner part is for browsers which don't support frames.

Comment: Simple basic solution, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: +1 for simple solution using only html tags

Answer (score 5):

use an ajax call to grab the php page from a url and then append the html that the php returns to an element on the javascript caller page.

In jquery it would look something like this in the javascript:

```
$.ajax(
           { 
               url: 'path_to_your_file.php',
               type: "POST",
               success: function(data)
               {
                   $('#div_id').append(data);
               }
           });
```

This is just a basic example. path_to_your_file.php would have to echo out the html to append it to that element. not sure if you use jquery or not but it is relatively simple this way.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Earlier I had a piece of code which just used a script tag and it worked fine, but I lost it.

Comment: You could use [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: i amended my answer, plus @yogu has an even simpler way.

Comment: it sounds like he wants to call the page from a different domain, in which case this call will fail in modern browsers due to the blocking of cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789604/insert-elements-at-script-tag-position). If you're dead-set on javascript, essentially what you want to do is include the page as an iframe at the script's location.

This is the same way as Google loads Adsense. In the setTimeout anon function, create an iframe which loads the page you want.

If you don't necessarily need to use javascript, you can do as Yogu suggested and simply use a hard-coded iframe.